# How to terminate the script in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exit, die

How can I exit the JavaScript script much like PHP's `exit` or `die`? I know it's not the best programming practice but I need to.

Comment: Do you think you could expand on this requirement, exactly why are you trying to achieve this ?

Comment: @andynormancx, this may be handy for debugging.

Comment: just `return;` might be enough depending on your requirements, acts like die() with no parameters.

Comment: why is always the first question 'why'?

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46307823/1442225)

Comment: The question is very simple and clear: it says "**terminate** the script". This means that the script is over. Finished. No more things should be expected to happen after that. It doesn't mean just "terminate a function". A `return` from a function (as suggested here) is **not a solution** because there may follow other things that will occur after that and the programmer wants to cancel them! I think it's very simple

Comment: In node you just write `process.exit(1)`, or other exit code you like.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[JavaScript equivalent for PHP's `die`](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/experimental/misc/die.js). BTW it just calls [`exit()`](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/experimental/misc/exit.js) (thanks splattne):

```
function exit( status ) {
    // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    // +   original by: Brett Zamir (http://brettz9.blogspot.com)
    // +      input by: Paul
    // +   bugfixed by: Hyam Singer (http://www.impact-computing.com/)
    // +   improved by: Philip Peterson
    // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brettz9.blogspot.com)
    // %        note 1: Should be considered expirimental. Please comment on this function.
    // *     example 1: exit();
    // *     returns 1: null

    var i;

    if (typeof status === 'string') {
        alert(status);
    }

    window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();}, false);

    var handlers = [
        'copy', 'cut', 'paste',
        'beforeunload', 'blur', 'change', 'click', 'contextmenu', 'dblclick', 'focus', 'keydown', 'keypress', 'keyup', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseout', 'mouseover', 'mouseup', 'resize', 'scroll',
        'DOMNodeInserted', 'DOMNodeRemoved', 'DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument', 'DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', 'DOMAttrModified', 'DOMCharacterDataModified', 'DOMElementNameChanged', 'DOMAttributeNameChanged', 'DOMActivate', 'DOMFocusIn', 'DOMFocusOut', 'online', 'offline', 'textInput',
        'abort', 'close', 'dragdrop', 'load', 'paint', 'reset', 'select', 'submit', 'unload'
    ];

    function stopPropagation (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // e.preventDefault(); // Stop for the form controls, etc., too?
    }
    for (i=0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
        window.addEventListener(handlers[i], function (e) {stopPropagation(e);}, true);
    }

    if (window.stop) {
        window.stop();
    }

    throw '';
}
```

Comment: Here's the source code of exit: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/javascript_equivalent_for_phps_exit/

Comment: That code doesn't appear to stop events on elements from firing, just the window's events. So you'd also need to loop through all the elements on the page doing something similar.
It all sounds like a very odd requirement though.

Comment: the whole die concept is a bit broken - the flow should be capable of handling any and all eventualities, whether that reqire try-catch or not.

Comment: I think you did not include all events that should be handled, such as "selectstart" event.

Comment: You can't stop XMLHttpRequest handlers. The current code does not stop intervals or timeouts from executing. Demo: jsfiddle.net/skibulk/wdxrtvus/1 You might consider this as a fix: stackoverflow.com/a/8860203/6465140

Comment: As of Google Chrome v62.0.3202.94 and Firefox v52.2.0, the *window.addEventListener* function now reports to the browser console as:

"Use of Mutation Events is deprecated.  Use MutationObserver instead."   

No idea what the workaround is.

Comment: Links of Exit.js are both dead but I've been able to find a backup on archive.org. So, just in case someone needs it... https://web.archive.org/web/20091002005151/http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net:80/techblog/article/javascript_equivalent_for_phps_exit

Comment: why does javascript need such convoluted hacks for basic, basic functionality that should just exist?

Answer (score 117):

"exit" functions usually quit the program or script along with an error message as paramete. For example die(...) in php

```
die("sorry my fault, didn't mean to but now I am in byte nirvana")
```

The equivalent in JS is to signal an error with the **throw** keyword like this:

```
throw new Error();
```

You can easily test this:

```
var m = 100;
throw '';
var x = 100;

x
>>>undefined
m
>>>100
```

Comment: @Sydwell : If you surround it by catch block, it will be caught and the program won't terminate, defying the point here.

Comment: Don't forget that you can add a message to the error: throw new Error('variable ='+x); It's a nice way to quickly end a script while  you're working on it and get the value of a variable.

Comment: @ultimate I think that #Sydwell ment to wrap the whole script in try/catch, so you can get a) clean exit b) possible exception message when needed :) Throwing uncought exceptions generally does not bring any good :)

Answer (score 67):

Even in simple programs without handles, events and such, it is best to put code in a `main` function, even when it is the only procedure :

```
<script> 
function main()
{
//code

}
main();
</script>
```

This way, when you want to stop the program you can use `return`.

Comment: Excellent. Clean, simple, effective. Thanks!

Comment: Works if you're a poor programmer and don't break your code into other functions. If you do, then a return inside a function that's inside a function won't do what you want.

Comment: Instead of a return, comment the `main` call.

Answer (score 26):

There are [many ways](http://stackabuse.com/how-to-exit-in-node-js/) to exit a JS or Node script. Here are the most relevant:

```
// This will never exit!
setInterval((function() {  
    return;
}), 5000);

// This will exit after 5 seconds, with signal 1
setTimeout((function() {  
    return process.exit(1);
}), 5000);

// This will also exit after 5 seconds, and print its (killed) PID
setTimeout((function() {  
    return process.kill(process.pid);
}), 5000);

// This will also exit after 5 seconds and create a core dump.
setTimeout((function() {  
    return process.abort();
}), 5000);
```

If you're in the [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) (i.e. after running `node` on the command line), you can type `.exit` to exit.

Comment: I didn't want to insult the intelligence of the readers by explaining an acronym that shows up as the first result of Googling it. I suggest you don't mix JavaScript code with REPL commands because if a user copy/pastes that code block and runs it, they'll get a Syntax error on the ".exit" line.

Comment: @Dan  Expanding, or explaining, an acronym is definitely not any insult. The need to expand, or explain, an acronym depends on the individual reader. A reader who is unfamiliar with the acronym appreciates the explanation and finds the reading uninterrupted , whereas a reader who is familiar with the acronym becomes assured that the writer's intent of the acronym matches the reader's understanding.

Answer (score 23):

If you don't care that it's an error just write:

```
fail;
```

That will stop your main (global) code from proceeding.
Useful for some aspects of debugging/testing.

Comment: `window.fail` isn't defined in current browsers.

Comment: That's the point - you could also do `mikeyMouse;` - the error will terminate. It's quick and dirty.

Comment: Ah fair enough - maybe add that to your answer?

Comment: yes it could be helpful for people to know that you're just forcing a ReferenceError by calling an undefined variable

Comment: For debugging purposes (because otherwise you don't care), if one is to exit in a quick and "dirty" way, then better show a (recognizable) message with `throw(message)`

Answer (score 11):

Javascript can be disabled in devtools: `ctrl+shift+j` followed `cltf+shift+p` then type `disable javascript`

Possible options that mentioned above:

```
window.stop(); // equivalent to the 'stop' button in the browser
debugger; // debugs
for(;;); // crashes your browser
window.location.reload(); // reloads current page
```

If page is loaded and you don't want to debug crash or reload:

```
throw new Error();
```

Additionally clear all [timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860188/javascript-clear-all-timeouts)

```
var id = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);
while (id--) {
    window.clearTimeout(id);
}
```

abort [DOM/XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

```
$.xhrPool = [];
$.xhrPool.abortAll = function() {
    $(this).each(function(i, jqXHR) { 
        jqXHR.abort();  
        $.xhrPool.splice(i, 1); 
    });
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) { $.xhrPool.push(jqXHR); },
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
        var i = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
        if (i > -1) $.xhrPool.splice(i, 1); 
    }
});
```

remove [all event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569393/how-to-unbind-all-event-using-jquery) including [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687790/how-to-remove-onclick-with-jquery)

```
$("*").prop("onclick", null).off();
```

this removes scripts and recreates elements without events

```
$('script').remove();
$('*').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).clone());   
});
```

If jQuery is not available on the webpage copy-paste [source code](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js) into a console.

There're might be other stuff. Let me know in a comment.

Comment: Clearing timeouts combined with some of the other answers did the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

Place the `debugger;` keyword in your JavaScript code where you want to stop the execution. Then open your favorite browser's developer tools and reload the page. Now it should pause automatically. Open the **Sources** section of your tools: the `debugger;` keyword is highlighted and you have the option to resume script execution.

I hope it helps.

*More information at:*

- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Tools/Debugger
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp

Answer (score 9):

In JavaScript multiple ways are there, below are some of them

**Method 1:**

```
throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");
```

**Method 2:**

```
return;
```

**Method 3:**

```
return false;
```

**Method 4:**

```
new new
```

**Method 5:**

write your custom function use above method and call where you needed

**Note:**
If you want to just pause the code execution you can use

```
debugger;
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case I used [`window.stop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop).

> The `window.stop()` stops further resource loading in the current browsing context, equivalent to the *'stop'* button in the browser.
>
> Because of how scripts are executed, this method cannot interrupt its parent document's loading, but it will stop its images, new windows, and other still-loading objects.
>
> **Usage**:  `window.stop();`
> <sub>([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/stop))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I think this question has been answered, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution) for more information. Below is the short answer it is posted.

```
throw new Error("Stop script");
```

You can also used your browser to add break points, every browser is similar, check info below for your browser.

For Chrome break points info click [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)
For Firefox break    points info click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint)
For Explorer break points info [click](https://raygun.com/blog/debug-javascript-internet-explorer/)
For Safari break points info click [here](https://raygun.com/blog/debug-javascript-safari/)

Comment: This is the answer I needed. A simple button that stops execution: the Chrome debugger's Pause button.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to stop further code from executing without "throwing" any error, you can temporarily override `window.onerror` as shown in [`cross-exit`](https://github.com/Richienb/cross-exit/blob/master/browser.js):

```js
function exit(code) {
    const prevOnError = window.onerror
    window.onerror = () => {
        window.onerror = prevOnError
        return true
    }

    throw new Error(`Script termination with code ${code || 0}.`)
}

console.log("This message is logged.");
exit();
console.log("This message isn't logged.");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to forcibly terminate execution of all Javascript on a page, I'm not sure there is an officially sanctioned way to do that - it seems like the kind of thing that might be a security risk (although to be honest, I can't think of how it would be off the top of my head). Normally in Javascript when you want your code to stop running, you just `return` from whatever function is executing. (The `return` statement is optional if it's the last thing in the function and the function shouldn't return a value) If there's some reason returning isn't good enough for you, you should probably edit more detail into the question as to why you think you need it and perhaps someone can offer an alternate solution.

Note that in practice, most browsers' Javascript interpreters will simply stop running the current script if they encounter an error. So you can do something like accessing an attribute of an unset variable:

```
function exit() {
    p.blah();
}
```

and it will *probably* abort the script. But you shouldn't count on that because it's not at all standard, and it really seems like a terrible practice.

*EDIT*: OK, maybe this wasn't such a good answer in light of Ólafur's. Although the `die()` function he linked to basically implements my second paragraph, i.e. it just throws an error.

Comment: All that will do will stop the current executing bit of scripting. It won't stop new events from firing and running new bits of script.

Comment: Not to mention, you don't need an extra bad function to throw an error. Javascript has a built-in throw statement.

Comment: The die function does a lot more than your p.blah(), it runs through the windows events and replaces the handles they have with "e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();", which will stop the events firing. _Then_ it throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

#### throw "";

Is a misuse of the concept but probably the only option. And, yes, you will have to reset all event listeners, just like the accepted answer mentions. You would also need a single point of entry if I am right.

On the top of it: You want a page which reports to you by email as soon as it throws - you can use for example Raven/Sentry for this. But that means, you produce yourself false positives. In such case, you also need to update the default handler to filter such events out or set such events on ignore on Sentry's dashboard.

#### window.stop();

This does not work during the loading of the page. It stops decoding of the page as well. So you cannot really use it to offer user a javascript-free variant of your page.

#### debugger;

Stops execution only with debugger opened. Works great, but not a deliverable.

Answer (score 0):

This little function comes pretty close to mimicking PHP's exit(). As with the other solutions, don't add anything else.

```
function exit(Msg)
    {
    Msg=Msg?'*** '+Msg:'';
    if (Msg) alert(Msg);
    throw new Error();
    } // exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use any undefined function in the script then script will stop due to "Uncaught ReferenceError". I have tried by following code and first two lines executed.

I think, this is the best way to stop the script. If there's any other way then please comment me. I also want to know another best and simple way. BTW, I didn't get exit or  die inbuilt function in Javascript like PHP for terminate the script. If anyone know then please let me know.

```
alert('Hello');

document.write('Hello User!!!');

die();  //Uncaught ReferenceError: die is not defined

alert('bye');

document.write('Bye User!!!');
```

Comment: It does terminate the rest of the code but with this at least you can give it an error message. `throw new Error('\r\n\r\nError Description:\r\nI\'m sorry Dave, I\'m afraid I can\'t do that.');`

Answer (score 0):

I am using iobroker and easily managed to stop the script with

```
stopScript();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if you want a similar PHP `die()` function, you could do:

```js
function die(reason) {
    throw new Error(reason);
}
```

Usage:

```js
console.log("Hello");
die("Exiting script..."); // Kills script right here
console.log("World!");
```

The example above will only print "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

Wrapp with a function

```
(function(){
alert('start')

return;
alert('no exec')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

i use this piece of code to stop execution:

```
throw new FatalError("!! Stop JS !!");
```

you will get a console error though but it works good for me.

Answer (score -1):

To stop script execution without any error, you can include all your script into a function and execute it.
Here is an example:

```js
(function () {
    console.log('one');
    return;
    console.log('two');
})();
```

The script above will only log **one**.

**Before use**

- If you need to read a function of your script outside of the script itself, remember that (normally) it doesn't work: to do it, you need to use a pre-existing variable or object (you can put your function in the *window* object).
- The above code could be what you don't want: put an entire script in a function can have other consequences (ex. doing this, the script will run immediately and there isn't a way to modify its parts from the browser in developing, as I know, in Chrome)

Answer (score -2):

This is an example, that,
if a condition exist, then terminate the script.
I use this in my SSE client side javascript, if the

```
<script src="sse-clint.js" host="https://sse.host" query='["q1,"q2"]' ></script>
```

canot be parsed right from JSON parse ...

```
if( ! SSE_HOST  ) throw new Error(['[!] SSE.js: ERR_NOHOST - finished !']);
```

... anyway the general idea is:

```
if( error==true) throw new Error([ 'You have This error' ,  'At this file', 'At this line'  ]);
```

this will terminate/die your javasript script

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. They're talking about a general problem, nothing to do with your specific SSE variables/file.

Comment: mjk - better now ?

Answer (score -2):

Simply create a BOOL condition ,
no need for complicated code here..

If even once you turn it to true/ or multiple times,
it will both give you one line of solution/not multiple -
basically simple as  that.

Comment: the question is the action, not the condition that triggers the action.

Answer (score -3):

Not applicable in most circumstances, but I had lots of async scripts running in the browser and as a hack I do

```
window.reload();
```

to stop everything.

Answer (score -3):

This code will stop execution of all JavaScripts in current window:

```js
    for(;;);
```

**Example**

```js
console.log('READY!');

setTimeout(()=>{

  /* animation call */ 
  div.className = "anim";

  console.log('SET!');

  setTimeout(()=>{

    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('this code will never be executed');
    },1000);

    console.log('GO!');

    /* BOMB */
    for(;;);

    console.log('this code will never be executed');

  },1000);

},1000);
```

```css
#div {
  position: fixed;
  height: 1rem; width: 1rem;
  left:   0rem; top:   0rem;
  transition: all 5s;
  background: red;
}
/* this <div> will never reached the right bottom corner */
#div.anim {
  left: calc(100vw - 1rem);
  top:  calc(100vh - 1rem);
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Just crashes the whole thing.

Comment: @Ste Sometimes, when you need to stop the execution of the script outside the current control flow, or stop all WebWorkers working in different obfuscated scripts connected to the current page, with only console and 10 seconds to think, there is no alternative solution.

Comment: Does `throw new Error('\r\n\r\nError Description:\r\nI\'m sorry Dave, I\'m afraid I can\'t do that.');` not work?

Comment: Well, this is cool! I guess my environment didn't like it and crashed. It's a windows app and not web-based. `throw new...` is what worked.

Comment: @Ste The infinite loop supersedes all executable libuv threads and runs until the stack is fully overflowed.

Answer (score -4):

i use return statement instead of throw as throw gives error in console. the best way to do it is to check the condition

```
if(condition){
 return //whatever you want to return
}
```

this simply stops the execution of the program from that line, instead of giving any errors in the console.

Comment: It, however, gives the error in your linters as "Can't use 'return' outside of function"

Comment: It stops execution because the statement is invalid. You could also use `if (condition) { new new }` or `if (condition) { purpleMonkeyDishwasher(); }`.