# Early exit from function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function myfunction() {
  if (a == 'stop')  // How can I stop the function here?
}
```

Is there something like `exit()` in JavaScript?

Comment: do you want to stop the execution or return?

Comment: @Ken Struys what is the difference? as i understand, if i make return, it stops the execution? isn't it?

Comment: Well here's the thing, using a return will just return to the context of the calling function. If you actually want the exit semantic you want to stop execution, you could do something like this: 

http://vikku.info/codesnippets/javascript/forcing-javascript-to-abort-stop-javascript-execution-at-any-time/

Comment: @Ken - That link you provided deals with stopping execution of a `for` loop. Even then, I have no idea why the method suggested would be used, when you could just call `break;`. To use the example from the article: `if(i==5) break;` Using `return` will halt the execution of the function, whether or not you're in a `for` loop.

Comment: Syom - Yes, `return` will stop the execution of the function, which seems to be what you asked.

Comment: @patrick yes that example is for iteration but the behavior of javascript_abort is very different from a break, or a return. Here's a better example:

function a() {
 b();
 alert("wont execute");
}

function b() {
 if(true) {
  alert('going to abort');
  javascript_abort();
 }
}

function javascript_abort()
{
   throw new Error('This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript');
}

a();

Note that if you used a return the second alert would be called. I'm not advocated this as a good solution it's just a way to get a exit like behavior.

Answer (score 748, accepted):

You can just use `return`.

```
function myfunction() {
     if(a == 'stop') 
         return;
}
```

This will send a return value of `undefined` to whatever called the function.

```
var x = myfunction();

console.log( x );  // console shows undefined
```

Of course, you can specify a different return value. Whatever value is returned will be logged to the console using the above example.

```
return false;
return true;
return "some string";
return 12345;
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, and this is common practice BUT I think this is a bad solution. If the function is SUPPOSED to return a value, you should use return. If you just blindly use return you might run into problems later. Especially if you start binding events that have a return in them. Check out this post for more info: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: @dbme: Functions in JavaScript *always* return. The return statement is implicit if it hasn't been provided. The default return value is `undefined`, and that's what my primary solution provides. The article you referenced is talking about doing `return false` in a jQuery event handler. That's an entirely different issue. This is the proper way to exit a JavaScript function. Obviously if the caller relies on the value returned, the value needs to be defined appropriately.

Comment: ...An implicit variation would be `if(a != 'stop') { /* run my code */ }` so that the code only runs when `a` doesn't equal `'stop'` without providing an explicit `return`. But the return value *is identical to my solution*. In both cases, `undefined` will be returned.

Comment: Awesome response. I didn't realize there was any difference between returning undefined vs false vs a different value. I've been trying to find a definitive answer regarding this behavior for the past hour. So is it safe to say (to reiterate your point) that return is a 100% safe way to exit a method, even if the caller is bound to events etc?

Comment: @dbme: Well, it all depends on what is expected by the method calling the function. If some code library defines an event system that will break if it receives `undefined` (or it doesn't receive some other value) as a return value, then you'll need to conform to the specification of that API, and return the correct value. Generally for an event handling system, it will expect `undefined` as a simple indication that the handler has finished, and there are no further instructions. With jQuery, `return false;` has special meaning giving instruction to do a `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`.

Comment: Again, awesome response. And for those like me who had no real idea how to use return properly, here's a test case: http://jsfiddle.net/GpEtq/ Works perfectly. Thanks @patrick-dw

Comment: Even though you could rely on impicit `undefined` return or explicit (`return;`) , you should always return something "readable" when you evaluate function's return value - someday someone might want that, however if you make a "procedure" (where return value is not evaluated) - there is no need for that :)

Comment: This solution actually doesn't always work. Here's a use case where it doesn't `const func = function(){

    ["item1", "item2", "item3"].forEach(item => {
        if (item === "item1"){
            checker = true
            return item
        }
    })


    if(checker){
        console.log("This should not print")
    }

    return undefined
}

console.log(func())`

You can put that in a file like `test.js` and then run `node test.js` to see what happens.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, I forgot that I was using a nested inline function, and that the return would be returning from the inline function

Answer (score 58):

Apparently you can do this:

```
function myFunction() {myFunction:{
    console.log('i get executed');
    break myFunction;
    console.log('i do not get executed');
}}
```

See block scopes through the use of a label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

I can't see any downsides yet. But it doesn't seem like a common use.

Derived this answer: [JavaScript equivalent of PHP’s die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361437/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-die)

Comment: is it possible to use this solution with nodejs exports module? when I try it I get "not used label" error. exports.MyFunction = function(data){myFunction:{break myFunction;}}

Answer (score 24):

```
function myfunction() {
     if(a == 'stop') 
         return false;
}
```

`return false;` is much better than just `return;`

Comment: Why is `false` better?  I'd say the default `undefined` is better in the generic case.  Either way, you're correct to say it's often better to return a meaningful value.

Comment: It's up to the programmer and dependant on the use case. For example, a function might validate something, so if the validation fails it makes more sense to return `false` than `undefined`.

Answer (score 17):

This:

```
function myfunction()
{
     if (a == 'stop')  // How can I stop working of function here?
     {
         return;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Using a little different approach, you can use `try catch`, with throw statement.

```
function name() {
    try {
        ...

        //get out of here
        if (a == 'stop')
            throw "exit";

        ...
    } catch (e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the only way to actually stop execution. However, I do think the original poster is speaking about returning from a function early. (Someone made a 1 minute youtube video on this that I just found, haha [break out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9U0vmbNy128). After all, you can technically decide to throw an exception based on return value in the outside scope. (Which in my opinion would have been more proper logically.)

Comment: It is a bad practice to control flows with exceptions. More details https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking for a script to avoid submitting form when some errors found, this method should work

```
function verifyData(){
     if (document.MyForm.FormInput.value.length == "") {
          alert("Write something!");
     }
     else {
          document.MyForm.submit();
     }
}
```

change the **Submit Button** type to "button"

```
<input value="Save" type="button" onClick="verifyData()">
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `return` will stop the function and return `undefined`, or the value that you specify with the return command.

```
function myfunction(){
    if(a=="stop"){
        //return undefined;
        return; /** Or return "Hello" or any other value */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think throw a new error is good approach to stop execution rather than just return or return false. For ex. I am validating a number of files that I only allow max five files for upload in separate function.

```js
validateMaxNumber: function(length) {
   if (5 >= length) {
        // Continue execution
   }
   // Flash error message and stop execution
   // Can't stop execution by return or return false statement; 
   let message = "No more than " + this.maxNumber + " File is allowed";
   throw new Error(message);
}
```

But I am calling this function from main flow function as

```
  handleFilesUpload() {
      let files =  document.getElementById("myFile").files;
      this.validateMaxNumber(files.length);
}
```

In the above example I can't stop execution unless I throw new Error.Just return or return false only works if you are in main function of execution otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: But the function keeps executing after I throw an error.

Comment: No `throw new Error()` is used when really some thing went wrong. If you want to exit function use `return true/false`. Big applications are saving errors and it will be sad if it will log thousand of errors from correct working code.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike answering things that aren't a real solution...

...but when I encountered this same problem, I made below workaround:

```
function doThis() {
  var err=0
  if (cond1) { alert('ret1'); err=1; }
  if (cond2) { alert('ret2'); err=1; }
  if (cond3) { alert('ret3'); err=1; }
  if (err < 1) {
    // do the rest (or have it skipped)
  }
}
```

Hope it can be useful for anyone.

Comment: Duh.  That's so simple I never thought of it!!  Pretty useful to avoid big nested IF's.  Thanks.

Comment: This would be better with a switch.

Comment: Depends if you wish to have all error alerts at once, of be notified of just one. However each condition needs to be executed anyway.

Answer (score -4):

If you are using jquery.  This should stop the function from bubbling up to so the parent function calling this should stop as well.

```
  function myfunction(e)
  {
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       ................
  }
```

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation()` is not a jQuery thing, and stopping propagation is not the same thing as exiting a function.

Answer (score -5):

exit(); can be use to go for the next validation.

Answer (score -22):

type any random command that throws an error, for example:

```
exit
```

or

```
die:-)
```

Comment: This may stop all code from being executed, not only the rest of the function. Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b3k0xo7n/1/

Comment: What a terrible programming approach. How is this intuitive for another developer who works on the same codebase?