# jquery javascript avoid running function on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I've a set of jquery and generally javascript function in a js. Now I want to avoid some of the functions to be available on some condition. For example:

```
function test () {
    alert("hi");
}

function avoid () {
   if(condition)  {
     //here avoid to call test
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you share some more information to check on what you require? A jsfiddle link would be good.

Comment: Ehrrm.. I'd suggest just to *not call* the function.

Comment: Could `condition` be evaluated within `test()` itself? Like for instance `function test() { if (!condition) { alert("hi"); } }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a function without errors (provided the caller of the function doesn't expect a returned result), you might do

```
function avoid () {
   if(condition)  {
     test = function(){}; // does nothing
   }
}
```

Note that if your `avoid` function is in a different scope, you might have to adapt. For example if `test` is defined in the global scope, then you'd do `window.test = function(){};`

Comment: And you could add `test.old = test` to keep the old function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question well but if the call to your test function is within the avoid function like below:

```
function test () {
    alert("hi");
}

function avoid () {
   if(condition)  {
     //here avoid to call test
    return false;
   }
   test();
}
```

Then a simple return false could solve your problem, I am not sure if your functions are using events but if that is the case this is a good post that you can read about preventDefault and return false : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

if test is at the same level of avoid like below :

```
function test () {
alert("hi");
}

function avoid () {
   if(condition)  {
     //here avoid to call test
    return false;
   }
   return true;
}

// below is your functions call
   check =  avoid();

   if(check){
    test();
   }
```

This post explains how to exit from a function: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330193/early-exit-from-function)

I hope that helps.