# What is the equivalent of prototype .any in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

We have one function called `.any` in Prototype. I want the same like in Jquery.

My Prototype code is:

```
 if (item_name == '' || $R(1,ind).any(function(i){return($F("bill_details_"+i+"_narration") == item_name)})) {
     alert("This item already added.");
 }
```

I want to perform the Equivalent function using Jquery.

Please help me to achieve the desired output. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: if anybody is giving downvote. please comment the reason..

Comment: what is inside `ind` and `$F`?

Comment: ind is a number like total number of rows. 1,2,...

Comment: @jantimon the use of this code is to avoid duplication of items. one item is added once we shouldnt allow to add again.

Comment: So you don't have an array at all?

Comment: this (1,ind) will make an array. for example if ind is 5 it will make [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: $(1,ind) with ind = 5 will not make an array [1,2,3,4,5] but [1,5]

Comment: @ChristopheDebove $R(1,5) will make an array [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @poojaagarwal did you miss out the `R` from `$R` in the question?

Comment: yes @Alnitak . i missed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For IE 9+ it's built in:

> The some() method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10].some(function(n) { return n > 5; });
// -> true (the iterator will return true on 6)
```

For IE 8 and below:

Prototype [any](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Enumerable/prototype/any/)

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10].any(function(n) { return n > 5; });
// -> true (the iterator will return true on 6)
```

You can use `jQuery.grep`:

```
jQuery.grep([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], function(n) { return n > 5; }).length > 0;
// -> true (as grep returns [6, 8, 10])
```

Underscore  `_.any` or `_.some`

```
_.any([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], function(n) { return n > 5; });
// -> true (the iterator will return true on 6)
```

Comment: can u post the equivalent jquery for my above prototype code. Please

Comment: `$F` is still using Prototype, not jQuery.

Comment: As for performance though, be wary that .any should stop looking after the first occurence, while .grep will traverse the entire array.

Comment: I wonder if you can use something liek this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22268145/582917 to break out of the non-short circuiting versions of the aggregation functions.

Comment: for jquery, $.grep().length is not as efficient as $.is()

Answer (score 5):

ES5 has a built-in function called [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which tests for whether *any* element in an array matches a predicate function, and which stops iterating as soon as a matching element is found.

```
.some(function(el) {
    return el.value === item_name;
});
```

Your problem then just becomes one of creating an array of the desired elements, which is harder than it would be in Prototype because there's no "range" operator in jQuery.  Fortunately `$.map` iterates over empty elements, even though the built-in `Array.prototype.map` doesn't so you can use `new Array(ind)`:

```
var found = $.map(new Array(ind), function(_, x) {
    return "bill_details_" + (x + 1) + "_narration";
}).some(function(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    return el && (el.value === item_name);
});
```

The link above includes a shim for `.some` for older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

JQuery has [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) method, from documentation: `Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return *true* if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments`. Thus an equivalent code is:

```
 if (item_name == '' || $([1,ind]).is(function(i) { return $('#bill_details_'+i+'_narration').attr('name') == item_name; })) {
      alert("This item already added.");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/ is what you are looking for.

try

```
if (item_name == '' || $.grep([1,ind],function(i){return($("#bill_details_"+i+"_narration").attr("name") == item_name)}).length>0) {
     alert("This item already added.");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to JQuery's documentation if you return a false in the callback function it will break the loop:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

Taken from: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/