# Why return; does not stop the function?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I simplified, but the nature of the problem is the same:

```
var counter=0;

function test(){
    window.onclick="return;";
    t.value=counter;
    counter++;
    setTimeout(test,1000);
}

t=document.createElement("textarea");
document.body.insertBefore(t, document.body.firstChild);
test();
```

Sets up a timer, however, as you can see, the clock does not stop (i.e. function exits) after I clicked the window. So where is the problem?

**Edit**: The motivation of this question comes from:[Early exit from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330193/early-exit-from-function)

**Edit^2**: Then there is noway to make 'onlick' trigger the returning value of test()? (i.e. equivalent of asking whether a function can return as its super-function)

Comment: Really, did you write this yourself, and if so why would anything happen when clicking the window? The return is a string that has nothing to do with the timeout ?

Comment: `onclick` takes a function!

Comment: @tymeJV It can also take a string of Javascript, which will be evaluated.

Comment: @Barmar: Only the attribute, I think. `.onclick` needs to be assigned a function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nz23K/

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I stand corrected. I thought the attribute and property were equivalent.

Comment: Why would `return;` stop the function? `return;` isn't in the scope of `test()`.

Comment: @Barmar: [It doesn't seem to be specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers) what happens when a string is getting assigned. Opera at least does nothing, haven't tested other browsers yet.

Comment: I tried `window.onclick = 'alert("click!")'` in Chrome, it did nothing.

Comment: Yep, the equivalent event handling DOM properties need functions. Like many other HTML attributes, event handling attributes are processed and converted to functions for the DOM properties. This can be seen by doing something like `<div onclick="alert(1);"></div>` and `console.log(divRef.onclick)`.

Answer (score 2):

That function has long since exited when you're trying to call `return`. JavaScript isn't going to throw itself into a time machine and prevent the `setTimer` call from being executed. It's too late for that.

What you need to do is cancel the timer, and in order to do that you have to save a handle to it:

```
var counter = 0;
var timer;

function test(){
    window.onclick = function() {
      if (timer) { clearTimeout(timer) }
    }

    t.value=counter;
    counter++;
    timer = setTimeout(test,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every ten minutes, you tell your wife "if you see a postman, do nothing.". Unsurprisingly, when she sees a postman, she does nothing.

Basically, what you're doing is identical, but less secure, way of writing this:

```
window.onclick = function() {
  return;
}
```

i.e. when a click is detected, it executes a function that does nothing but return. It has nothing to do with the function `test`.

Comment: Actually, I'm unsure if setting the property `onclick` as a string will work: http://jsfiddle.net/kLvfX/ So technically, they are not identical (if it did work, the scope will be different and they are still not identical.)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Yeah, you might be right. I abandoned string event handlers years ago, not sure any more what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but this answer has reminded me a joke I think is worth sharing... http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/c9/c9ec3d95bb16919cfb1e2f90c9eafe12f6ef7b85771428561a7f8265ac2d6f4e.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the statement:

```
window.onclick="return;";
```

the string `"return;"` is assigned to the *window.onclick* property, which will replace the current value (whatever that might be).

If your intention was to end execution of the *test* function, then a [return statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) is required:

```
return;
```

The [*return* keyword](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1) must appear as the start of a statement, it can't be assigned.