# How to activate a script if a cell has a certain value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script in google sheets script which works fine.

```
function morningemail() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("clock script");
    var startRow = 9;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process

    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i]
        var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
        var message = row[2] + row[3]; // Second & third column
        var subject = row[1];    // First column
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

I will set the project trigger to activate every 5 minutes but only want the script to send an email if cell "A20" (on the same spreadsheet) is ">10".

I've tried a few ways of doing this but can't get it to work. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: suggest you show any of the few ways you tried

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Add `if( data[19][0]>10) return;` between the following lines:

```
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
```

## Explanation

In order to minimize the number of calls to the API, and considering that your script already got the data range values, use `data[19][0]` to get the value of `A20`, then use `if` to test if the desired condition is met and in such case use `return` to finalize the execution of the script.

## References

- [Early exit from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330193/early-exit-from-function)

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for that. It is still not working. I think I have simplified things by putting all my data on a single line in the spreadsheet. My code is still not working

Comment: I'm sorry the row/columns were switched. I just corrected them.