# Angularjs stop program execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to know how to stop the program from executing the remaining code when a particular if condition returns true.

code sample

```
if(qname == QueName) {
    exit();
}
```

I tried using break.  But Im getting an exception illegal use of break statement. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to stop?

Comment: If the above condition returns true, I want the program to stop execution break or exit the execution. The code after the if statement should not get executed.Im looking for an equivalent like break.

Comment: Are you in a function?

Comment: yes im inside a function and checking the if condition. If the condition is true, the program should terminate

Comment: [Early exit from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330193/early-exit-from-function)

Comment: please add a bigger part of the code to better clarify the issue

Answer (score 0):

Return from a function when its work is done:

```
if(qname == QueName) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Function will not execute once it has returned. You said you are inside a function. This code will definitly work. Ese, share rest of your code and elaborate your problem statement

Comment: return; statement will stop the execution of further lines of code. Thanks!