# Get index of item in Javascript Set

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time finding a dupe of this question, but I assume it's been asked before....

If I add three items to a `Set`:

```
var s = new Set();
undefined
s.add(1); s.add(2); s.add(3);
Set(3) {1, 2, 3}
```

... How can I find out the index of an item?

There is no `indexOf` method for `Set` and I'm not sure if iterating over the Set is the best way. I've tried using the `forEach` API but can neither `break` nor `return` from this function:

```
  if (s.size < cells.length) {
    var count = 0;
    s.forEach(function (value) {
      if (cell.id.slice(0, -5) == value) {
        break;  //return fails here too...
      }
      count ++;
    });
    return count;
  }
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330193/early-exit-from-function for your 'break'/'return' part

Comment: not relevant to my question ^^ about getting an item's index in a Set

Comment: @JacobIRR It is relevant to the 'break'/'return' part. As you say, if you could break the function, you would have your solution.

Comment: @JacobIRR it's the spread operator (...) all it does is copy all the elements in the set into the array e.g
`const numbers = [1, 2, 3];` `console.log(sum(...numbers));`
// expected output: 6 `console.log(sum.apply(null, numbers));`
// expected output: 6

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The purpose of Sets is not so much to give an order number, but if you need one, the pragmatic solution is to temporarily turn it into an array with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
count = [...s].indexOf(cell.id.slice(0, -5));
```

If for some reason you prefer looping, then use `some` instead of `forEach`:

```
const target = cell.id.slice(0, -5);
[...s].some(function (value) {
  if (value === target) {
    return true; // this will stop the iteration
  }
  count ++;
});
```

Or why not use the ES6 `for of` loop, which avoids the conversion to array -- a conversion which for large sets is not an interesting option:

```
const target = cell.id.slice(0, -5);
for (const value of s) {
  if (value === target) {
    break; // this will stop the iteration
  }
  count ++;
}
```

NB: Although the use of the old-style `for ... in` loop is discouraged for use with arrays, this does not hold for the `for ... of` loop.

Comment: What is `[...s]` ? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @JacobIRR: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator ... you can also use `Array.from(s)` instead.

Comment: ahh yes `from` is great. Thanks to you both. This works.

Comment: The performance of turning a big set into an array is pretty bad.

Comment: Yes, @max, absolutely. I expanded on that just now, in promoting the last option in my answer.