# Else condition is not working

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS. So i'm trying to create a function but the "else" part is not working. Can you help me to understand why?

```js
function accesSite() {
    let ageLimite = prompt("How old are you ?");
    if (ageLimite >= 16) {
        var yes = " Ok, you can drive ! ";
    } else {
        var no = "No, you can't drive!";
    }
    let message = "Can you drive ?" + yes || no;
    return message
}

alert(accesSite());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like below. Declare a variable and then change it accordingly:

```js
 function accesSite(){
     let ageLimite = prompt("How old are you ?") >= 16;
     //create variable
     var canDrive = "";
     if (ageLimite >= 16){
         //change it accordingly
         canDrive = " Ok, you can drive ! " ;
     } else {
         //change it accordingly
         canDrive = "No, you can't drive!" ;
     }
     let message =  "Can you drive ? " +  canDrive ;
     return message
}

alert(accesSite());
```

A better version in a single line:

```js
function accesSite(){
    return "Can you drive ? " + ( prompt("How old are you ?") >= 16 ? " Ok, you can drive ! " : "No, you can't drive!");
}

alert(accesSite());
```

Comment: This method of working makes more sense than the answer of @Nina Scholz: creating 1 variable for 1 purpose.

Comment: While this is the better option, this has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: This is so much better, thanks you for the refactoring :-) It's very cool :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use parenthesis for the [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), because the plus has a higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) as the logical OR.

```
let message =  "Can you drive? " + (yes || no);
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ evaluate first
```

---

A better approach would be to declare all constants and variables on top and return with the result directly without taking another variable for the return string.

The function feature the *early exit* paradigm, that means if you need to return from a function, you could organize the condition/s in the way that you do not need `else` parts, because you use `return` for terminating the function at early stage.

Sources:

- [Wikipedia: Structured programming: Early exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit)
- [Should I return from a function early or use an if statement?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)
- [Early exit from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330193/early-exit-from-function)

```js
function accesSite(){
    const canYouDrive = "Can you drive? ";
    var ageLimite = prompt("How old are you?");

    if (ageLimite >= 16){
        return canYouDrive + "Ok, you can drive!";
    } 
    return canYouDrive + "No, you can't drive!" ;
}

alert(accesSite());
```

Comment: This answer solves the problem but not the bad practice. Scoping of the variable is the issue here: OP is creating 2 variables for 1 purpose (appending it to the final message).

Comment: @NinaScholz I must have still been typing my comment while you added this to your answer afterwards, but you're right. :)

Comment: " _Beside that, i suggest to use only one variable for the result string and declare all variables at top of the function._ ". Well, _do_ that when you write your answer...

Comment: I'm at a loss for words why this _"bandage"_ is getting this many votes. It's not fixing any of the glaring issues in the question. It's just making the OP's code work at all costs... I'd expect more from a high rep user that is meant to serve as an __example.__

Comment: My comment isn't rude. It's blunt, at most. The only reason I added my answer, is because there wasn't a __proper__ answer here, yet. Only bandages.

Answer (score 3):

While we're fixing it, we can make the code even cleaner:

```js
function accesSite(){
    let ageLimite = prompt("How old are you ?");
    let message =  "Can you drive ? ";

    if (ageLimite >= 16)
        return message + " Ok, you can drive !";

    return message + "No, you can't drive!" ;
}

alert(accesSite());
```

Note that I removed the `else` block here:

- If the condition is `true`, then you hit a `return statement`. Nothing below that `return` can be executed.
- The other way around, if the condition is `false`, the first block will not be executed, the `if`'s `return` will no be called, so the code below the `if` is executed instead.

---

Or by using a [ternary condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
function accesSite(){
    let ageLimite = prompt("How old are you ?");
    return "Can you drive ? " + (ageLimite >= 16 ? " Ok, you can drive!" : "No, you can't drive!");
}

alert(accesSite());
```

I personally prefer keeping the `prompt` result in a variable. Imo, that's more readable.

Comment: Wow! but i dont understand how it's possible to use the line "no" without an "else" in your exemple.

Comment: @Gabriel: If the condition is `true`, then you hit a `return` statement. Nothing below that can be executed. The other way around, if the condition is `false`, the first block will not be executed, the `return` will no be called, so the code below the `if` is executed instead.

Comment: @Nick: If the user closes the prompt, the return value will be "falsy", any way.

Answer (score 1):

```
function accesSite() {
    let ageLimite = prompt("How old are you ?");
    var msg = "Can you drive ? ";
    if (ageLimite >= 16) {
        msg = msg  + " Ok, you can drive ! ";
    } else {
        msg = msg  + "No, you can't drive!";
    }
    let message = msg;
    return message
}

alert(accesSite());
```