# React search onChange cancel request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm handling search feature onChange using Axios. It works fine.

But the problem is when the user deletes input to empty. The request still sent.

My code.

```
    handleSearch = (e) => {
    const query = e.target.value;
    if(this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout);

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (query === '') // do something ????

        requestApi.searchMultiData('search/multi', query)
            .then(response => {
                this.props.data(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, 300);
    };
```

How can I handle that? My solution is when text input empty. The request should be canceled. Any ideas for working with that? Tks.

Comment: `if (query !== '') {

        requestApi.searchMultiData('search/multi', query) .... `

Comment: Or `if (query === '') return` (right after your declaration)

Comment: Thank guys, its work. Sorry my simple question.

Comment: Actually: 
`handleSearch = (e) => {
    const query = e.target.value;
    if(this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    if (query === '')  return;
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this again, I suggest this:

```
handleSearch = (e) => { 
  const query = e.target.value; 
  if (this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout); 
  if (query.trim() === '') return; // here is the logical place to leave
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to [early exit from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330193/early-exit-from-function). It means that a part or most of the code in your callback function will not be executed if a condition is met (`query` is empty: see how to implement it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)).

I'd also recommend using [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove the whitespace; otherwise, values like  will be considered correct, which they are probably not.