# How do I terminate Javascript execution, á la exit/die/fatal assertion, etc.?

Tags: javascript, fatal-error, assertion, termination

I have a loop in Javascript, I want to run `console.log()` in a specific iteration, and then terminate. What is the best method to go about doing this?

I'm wanting something like Perl's

```
die Dumper \@foo;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent of PHP’s die](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361437/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-die)

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an exception:

```
throw "Help I have fallen and cannot get up";
```

Not exactly the same, but (in my experience) it's not too common to see exception handling in ordinary DOM-wrangling sorts of JavaScript code, so that usually will blow out of any event loop.  However, it's not really the same thing as any surroundling `try` block will catch what you throw.

Answer (score 1):

you mean terminate loop?

```
while(true) {
console.log()
if(condition) {break};
}
```

the `break` command exits the loop

but there is no `kill` or `exit` function in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is event-based, a script doesn't control when it terminates — there's no `die` or `exit`.

If it's not one already, the best option is to refactor the code into a function that you can `return` from, or use a named block:

```
foo: {
    // do work
    break foo;
    // not executed;
}
```