# Best way to "Exit" in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, window.location

My goal is to:

```
if(error){
    window.location.href = "error.htm";
    //end of every thing
}
```

What's more, `return false` wouldnt help because there may be functions inside of functions.
My current solution is `throw`, but i feel uncomfortable

Any better idea || solution ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript and also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1361966/920173

Comment: it looks like everyone use 'throw'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to leave a function, I suppose you try to break for a loop.

Then you can use [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) :

```
function testBreak(x) {
   var i = 0;
 
   while (i < 6) {
      if (i == 3) {
         break;
      }
      i += 1;
   }
   return i * x;
}
```

*(MDN example)*

If you're trying to exit from more than one function, trough several stack call levels, then the only "valid" use case that comes to mind is the "exceptional" error, which can be handled with try/catch/throw as you saw. But abusing exception lead to hard to maintain code and often hides the errors. If you need it, your code probably doesn't really look javascript-esque.

Answer (score 0):

I use throw for exiting JS

```
throw new Error("my error message");
```

as described at ;

[JavaScript equivalent of PHP’s die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361437/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-die)