# Overwriting onclick value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I'm attempting to create a function that will select all anchor tags with both http and _gaq (because a lot of the links have event tracking on them), and then add Google Analytics [cross-domain tracking linker method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite) to the onclick event:

```
        $("a[href*='http:'][onclick*='_gaq']").each(function(){
            var href = this.href;
            var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
            var linker = "['_link', "+ "'"+href+"'"+"],";
            var output = [onclick.substr(0,10), linker, onclick.substr(10), " return false;"].join('');

            console.log('output : '+output);
         });
```

When I run this, it outputs:

`output : _gaq.push(['_link', 'http://google.com'],['_trackEvent','dude','dude','dude']); return false;`

This is what I'd like the new value for onclick to be, so I'm wondering how can I have the output value 'overwrite' the old onclick value?

I've also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EVMp/) to illustrate.

Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("a[href*='http:'][onclick*='_gaq']").each(function(e){
    var href = this.href;
    var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
    var linker = "['_link', "+ "'"+href+"'"+"],";
    var output = [onclick.substr(0,10), linker, onclick.substr(10), " return false;"].join('');
    $(this).attr('onclick', output);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687790/how-to-remove-onclick-with-jquery) which probably gets you the answer you want:

```
$("a[href*='http:'][onclick*='_gaq']").each(function(){
     var href = this.href;
     var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
     var linker = "['_link', "+ "'"+href+"'"+"],";
     var output = [onclick.substr(0,10), linker, onclick.substr(10), " return false;"].join('');

     $(this).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');  // Get rid of the old one
     var f = new Function(output);                // create a function
     $(this).click(f);                            // Add your new onclick
  });
```

**Edit: I was Led astray by a more recent comment with 26 upvotes. Switching back to my original form.**

26 votes Yet it doesn't seem to work!, compare

http://jsfiddle.net/TN2wr/

with

http://jsfiddle.net/TN2wr/1/

Comment: I appreciate all the documentation and fiddles, but ended up going with @Arun P Johny's answer due to the simplicity.

Comment: hmm, as long as you don't care about events added in javascript... http://jsfiddle.net/TN2wr/2/