# Remove <tr> onclick method using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove `<tr>` `onclick` method if child `<td>&nbsp;</td>` or `<td></td>` using jquery ?

```
  <tr title="Click to select row" class="gridItem" 
             onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Body$grdComments','Select$0')">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
  <tr title="Click to select row" class="SelectedRowStyle" 
             onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Body$grdComments','Select$0')">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: On click of what and what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

`.text` returns the (decoded) content of the element, so you just have to test whether a `tr` element only contains spaces or is empty:

```
$('tr').filter(function() {
    return /^\s*$/.test($(this).text());
}).prop('onclick', null);
```

Also see [How to remove "onclick" with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687790/how-to-remove-onclick-with-jquery).

Comment: I don't know why this is not working for me. I placed this in $(function(){ ... });

Comment: Since I don't know the rest of your code, I can't help you with that. it works fine by itself: http://jsfiddle.net/p44Sx/.