# Button clickable even though disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this code below to disable the buttons, its disabled. When I mouse over, it shows the crossed round icon, so all good. However, the issue is, when I click, behind the scene, it invokes click action or things that we expect to see on clicking when its not disabled.

I browsed the net and didn't fnd any solution except change from attr to prop. I am going to do this now and see, but sadly it works fine in Deb and not in UAT.

Any help please?

```
$("#IsMarriedlbl").attr("disabled", true);
$("#IsSinglelbl").attr("disabled", true);
$("#IsWidowedlbl").attr("disabled", true);
$("#Divorcedlbl").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: could you please post some html and the code for click event?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: How does that interests you? I reckon the correction needs to be done here. You do not have to worry about internal logic but the one that triggers that. I want some options like return false, or stopimmediatepropagation etc? Bad thing is, it works perfectly fine in Dev so I do not want to change this. My question is why not in other environ it doesn't work.

Comment: well there might be click a parent element of the disabled button which is being triggered and I can't be sure without seeing the code

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: Thank you, but I am afraid I dont know where it is, its a big messy solution. :(

Comment: Probably irrelevant, however you should be aware of the difference between `.attr()` and `.prop()` -- `disabled` is a _property_ of an element, controlled by using the _attribute_ `disabled` or `disabled="disabled"`; so when setting it programmatically it is "more correct" to use `.prop('disabled', true)`. There are some cases where changing an attribute after the DOM has been built (parsed) has no effect but changing the property _does_. (but can't remember an example at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but IE doesn't prevent the event from bubbling when you click a disabled submit button so you have to handle it in the click event as well. - bit of a nightmare.

If you return false on your click event it will prevent the code from running but still have the disabled effect to the user.

```
$('#yourClickEvent').click(function( event ) {
    var $isDisabled  = $(event.target);
    if( $isDisabled.is(':submit:disabled') ) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I saw the ditto statement and code in other question, but doesn't help.

Comment: it will return false and not allow the user to continue why does that not help.. disabled does not stop the click event on IE so you have to do this, test this in IE in dev and it wont work.

Comment: Hey, its even in Chrome :)

Comment: Working in  Chrome Dev (Haven't checked IE Dev lol)... But testers are after me, damn this silly bug not working in UAT but works fine in Dev :( and Local :( Have no clue, same code.

Comment: disabled only disables the user integration not the functionality sorry to say this but your going to have to do a check and return false on the click events. wont take long to add to your onclick events.

Comment: Ok I will do as you say and see if that helps

Comment: it will still trigger the click but your 'return false' will stop any functionality firing if you check at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an answer I've seen before @ [Much thanks to GhiOm for the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687790/how-to-remove-onclick-with-jquery):

**Old Way (pre-1.7):**

```
$('...').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```

**New Way (1.7+):**

```
$('...').prop('onclick',null).off('click');
```

Comment: you cant steal another question answer from stackoverflow itself lol

Comment: I don't really get how it's "stealing" when I'm both linking and crediting the original answer with what I assume is the answer to this problem.  It's not like I'm saying "this is mine".

Comment: you should comment with it normally.. not answer it again.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, but StackOverflow requires that I have 50 reputation to comment on an original question.  Since I have 16 I am unable to do what you are asking me to do.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @MikeS: Actually using prop only breaks my code and creates more problem than I have now lol

Comment: @JoshStevens: I replied him, his answer creates more problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable both clicking by humans and programmatically generated clicks, you need to do something like this :

```
$("#IsMarriedlbl")
    .prop('disabled', 'disabled')  // Sets 'disabled' property
    .prop('onclick', null)         // Removes 'onclick' property if found
    .off('click');                 // Removes other events if found
```

---

#### Demo

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    alert("clicked!");
});

$("#IsMarriedlbl")
    .prop('disabled', 'disabled')  // Sets 'disabled' property
    .prop('onclick', null)         // Removes 'onclick' property if found
    .off('click');                 // Removes other events if found

$("#IsMarriedlbl").click();
$("#IsMarriedlbl").click();
$("#IsMarriedlbl").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<button id="IsMarriedlbl">Married</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work for me and makes no difference from my code.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why: but here on codepen works fine:
[Button disabling test](http://codepen.io/ricardofilipe65/pen/dMzWjp)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").attr("disabled", true);

  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked!");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #52DD83;
  overflow: hidden;
}
button {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button">Button</button>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js" </script>
    < /body>
</html >
```