# activate/deactivate onclick attr after div click jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a `div` that have an onclick event, what I want is activate it or deactivated by clicking on other divs. I don't want to remove it, because I'll use thos onclick later

```
 <div id=goTo onclick="location.href='post.php?id=21';"> go to this page/div>
```

those are the buttons to click

```
<div id=deactivate>[click to deactivate]</div>
     <div id=reactivate>[click to reactivate]</div>
```

I want to deactivate/reactivate `#goTo`. I've tried `.removeAttr()` but I don't want to removed because I don't know how to restore it later

```
$("#deactivate").click(function(){
             $("#goTo").removeAttr("onclick");
   });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove "onclick" with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687790/how-to-remove-onclick-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

- You can keep a flag, which you can toggle on click of reactivate and deactivate and use that to change the url based on this value.
- Instead on inline onclick use `.on("click", callback)`

See the code below:

```
var flag = true;

$("#goTo").on("click", function(){
   if(!flag)
    return;
   location.href='post.php?id=21';
});


$("#deactivate").on("click", function(){
  flag = false;
})

$("#reactivate").on("click", function(){
  flag = false;
})
```

Comment: Ok thank you, the problem is that I already have set different configurations with this `onclick event`, so is better to keep it within the `div`as an attribute. I thought something like that but I would need to change a lot if I add this flag var. I think it is possible to find a solution as `onclick` as an attribute