# jQuery accordion not working after responsive resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The end result of this is to have an accordion that only works under 800px, and anything greater than that it is expanded. as of now, it works when:

1. the page is opened in a window with a width greater than 800px (accordion contents are locked and won't collapse)
2. the page is opened in a window with a width lesser than 800px (accordion contents are free to collapse and expand with the on click event)

and won't work when:

1. the page is opened in a window with a width greater than 800px, resized to lesser than 800px and then resized again to greater than 800px (accordion contents are free to collapse and expand with the on click event at any screen width)
2. the page is opened in a window with a width lesser than 800px and then resized to greater than 800px (accordion contents are free to collapse and expand with the on click event at any screen width)

[js fiddle to test window resizing](http://jsfiddle.net/q276xsbj/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=q276xsbj)

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  function accordion(match) {
    if (match.matches) {

      console.log("more than 800");

      $('.accordion-toggle').slideDown(600);

      $('#services, #accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {

      });

    } else {

      console.log("less than 800");

      $(".accordion-content").not($('.accordion-toggle').next()).slideUp(600);

      $('#services, #accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {

        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
        //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(500);

        $(this).off(event);

      });
    }
  }

  var match = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 800px)");
  accordion(match); // Call listener function at run time
  match.addListener(accordion); // Attach listener function on state changes
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.accordion-container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-toggle {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #31353D;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Martel Sans", sans-serif;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-toggle div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-toggle:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #1C1D21;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.accordion-container .accordion-toggle:hover .accordion-icon {
  color: #1C1D21;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(150%);
  filter: brightness(150%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-content.default {
  display: block;
  color: #31353D;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-content.default .service-list {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 100px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 100px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-family: "Martel Sans", sans-serif;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-content.default .service-list .service-list-item {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #445878;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-content.default .service-list .service-list-item span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 2px;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-content.default .service-details {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  color: #31353D;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-icon {
  color: #31353D;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.about-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.about-container .accordion-container .accordion-content.default {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.about-container .accordion-container .accordion-content.default .accordion-content-header {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.about-container .accordion-container .accordion-content.default .accordion-content-subheader {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #1C1D21;
  line-height: 1.1;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.jqueryHelper {
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .jqueryHelper {
    float: none;
  }
  .accordion-container {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 750px;
  }
  .accordion-container .accordion-toggle {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.9em;
  }
  .accordion-container .accordion-content {
    display: inline;
  }
  .accordion-container .accordion-content.default {
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #31353D;
  }
  .services-container .accordion-container .accordion-content.default {
    display: flex;
  }
  .about-continer .accordion-container .accordion-content.default {
    display: block;
  }
  .accordion-container .accordion-content.default .service-list {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 40%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 100px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 100px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .accordion-container .accordion-content.default .service-list .service-list-item small:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  .accordion-container .accordion-content.default .service-details {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    color: #31353D;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  .about-container .accordion-container .accordion-content.default {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="about-container" id="about">
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-container">
      <div class="accordion-toggle ">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-content default">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus arcu urna, finibus in nunc quis, porta rhoncus nunc. Sed pretium nunc a lobortis tempor. Morbi sit amet ipsum ut nunc rhoncus cursus sit amet sed nunc. Suspendisse in arcu vel enim tristique
        bibendum eu at erat. Sed id urna tincidunt, iaculis lacus nec, feugiat purus. Sed leo odio, fermentum a ipsum eu, faucibus facilisis tortor. Nam dignissim erat magna, at euismod risus imperdiet in. Mauris aliquam enim eget eros euismod, in sollicitudin
        turpis ultricies. Sed tincidunt maximus diam ut tincidunt. Cras eros ex, fringilla ac mattis ac, pellentesque eget neque. Nulla sed libero nibh. Proin ex metus, varius congue eros quis, volutpat lacinia mi. Pellentesque eu gravida eros. In hac
        habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce dictum sit amet felis fringilla laoreet. Sed ut lorem sed urna pharetra dictum id lobortis ex.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-container">
      <div class="accordion-toggle">
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-content default">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus arcu urna, finibus in nunc quis, porta rhoncus nunc. Sed pretium nunc a lobortis tempor. Morbi sit amet ipsum ut nunc rhoncus cursus sit amet sed nunc. Suspendisse in arcu vel enim tristique
        bibendum eu at erat. Sed id urna tincidunt, iaculis lacus nec, feugiat purus. Sed leo odio, fermentum a ipsum eu, faucibus facilisis tortor. Nam dignissim erat magna, at euismod risus imperdiet in. Mauris aliquam enim eget eros euismod, in sollicitudin
        turpis ultricies. Sed tincidunt maximus diam ut tincidunt. Cras eros ex, fringilla ac mattis ac, pellentesque eget neque. Nulla sed libero nibh. Proin ex metus, varius congue eros quis, volutpat lacinia mi. Pellentesque eu gravida eros. In hac
        habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce dictum sit amet felis fringilla laoreet. Sed ut lorem sed urna pharetra dictum id lobortis ex.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-container">
      <div class="accordion-toggle" style="border: none">
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-content default">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus arcu urna, finibus in nunc quis, porta rhoncus nunc. Sed pretium nunc a lobortis tempor. Morbi sit amet ipsum ut nunc rhoncus cursus sit amet sed nunc. Suspendisse in arcu vel enim tristique
        bibendum eu at erat. Sed id urna tincidunt, iaculis lacus nec, feugiat purus. Sed leo odio, fermentum a ipsum eu, faucibus facilisis tortor. Nam dignissim erat magna, at euismod risus imperdiet in. Mauris aliquam enim eget eros euismod, in sollicitudin
        turpis ultricies. Sed tincidunt maximus diam ut tincidunt. Cras eros ex, fringilla ac mattis ac, pellentesque eget neque. Nulla sed libero nibh. Proin ex metus, varius congue eros quis, volutpat lacinia mi. Pellentesque eu gravida eros. In hac
        habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce dictum sit amet felis fringilla laoreet. Sed ut lorem sed urna pharetra dictum id lobortis ex.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also, it appears that if you click the toggle more than once whilst it's moving it stacks up and won't stop until its completed all the animations.
is there a way to stop it from accepting the onclick event whilst its in motion?

Comment: can you use a disabled class thats removed after the animation is complete, then the onclick event can detect the if the disabled class exists before firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't understood 100% your test case, but I spotted a bug here:

```
$('#services, #accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {

  });
```

this won't unbind the action of the click, this snippet below will do the job ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687790/how-to-remove-onclick-with-jquery)):

```
  $('#services, #accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').prop('onclick',null).off('click');
```

In order to open all the content you have to add:

```
if (match.matches) {

   console.log("more than 800");

   //comment this one, it's useless
   //$('.accordion-toggle').slideDown(600);
   // this one will open all the contents
   $(".accordion-content").slideDown(600);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q276xsbj/2/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was aiming for, appreciate the help man!