# jquery split() and indexOf results in "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, arrays, split

I have the following code:

```
var selected = $('#hiddenField').val().split(",");
...
if (selected.indexOf(id) > 0) {
   ... set value ...
}
```

I'm dynamically creating a CheckBoxList, and trying to remember the state of the checkboxes by putting the selected IDs into the hidden field.

I get an error stating that "Object doesn't support this property or method".  My assumption is that selected is an array, which should support indexOf.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: Just as a hint, these are normal **Javascript** methods, they are not jQuery specific.

Comment: It'd probably help if you were to post more code.  Also, you should verify that what you *think* you're getting out of that hidden field is really what's in it.

Comment: @Felix:  I wasn't sure if there was a difference between the built-in split and the jquery split.

Comment: For a thorough explanation of the issue as well as a work around not only for indexOf but the other missing array functions in IE check out the StackOverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc

Answer (score 22):

There's an jQuery method to overcome the lack of `indexOf()`, you can use [`.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) instead:

```
var selected = $('#hiddenField').val().split(",");
if ($.inArray(id, selected) > -1) {
   ... set value ...
}
```

`jQuery.inArray()` exists for just this reason...if you're including jQuery already, no need to write the function again.  Note: This actually returns a number, like `indexOf()` would.

Comment: This seems like it should work, for some reason it's not:

>? line.id
101
>? selected
{...}
    [0]: "101"
    length: 1
>? $.inArray(line.id, selected)
-1
>

Answer (score 21):

Based on your error message, I'm assuming this is coming from Internet Explorer.

Surprise! Internet Explorer (including version 8) does not support indexOf for arrays.

Here is [Firefox's implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/IndexOf) you can use:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: @Matt: Thank you. I thought they'd implemented it in IE8, so went and did a quick experiement, and was pleasantly surprised to see it in IE7 as well. As you can guess, the experiment was flawed (I forgot to remove the reference to Prototype, which conveniently adds it if it's missing). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
[].indexOf || (Array.prototype.indexOf = function(v,n){
  n = (n==null)?0:n; var m = this.length;
  for(var i = n; i < m; i++)
    if(this[i] == v)
       return i;
  return -1;
});
```