# JavaScript indexOf vs Array.prototype.indexOf IE compatibility error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)

I recently developed a script that uses native Javascript and jQuery. Most of my development has been with IE 9, Chrome, Firefox. For all of them the line below works perfectly:

```
if(data.cols.indexOf("footprint") < 0)
```

However today I pushed a bit of my code to a production system and a couple of the clients have come back saying their pages are broken. I have narrowed my search down to `indexOf`, which apparently IE 8 does not like in the slightest. So I am trying to find an alternative and I found this bit `Array.prototype.indexOf` but I am not really sure how I would tie that into an if-else similar to above.

Also if there is a better alternative then I am all ears. Also, is this something I may have to apply to IE 8 browsers only, where if IE 8 is found, use this, if not use the original?

Comment: Array.prototype.indexOf was first supported in IE9, see [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for code you can include to support older versions of IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has come up many times, another Stackoverflow thread can be found here: [How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for Internet Explorer browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers/8813472#8813472)

Several people on different threads have recommended using [this code from MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility). This appears to be the code:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Just run this code before making any calls indexOf()