# Javascript get index of child on click

Tags: javascript

I've added a click event to a parent #carousel-thumbs.

```
carouselThumbsContainer.onclick = function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target;    // which child was actually clicked
}

<ul id="carousel-thumbs" class="l-grid">
    <li class="active"><a class="active" href="#"><img src="img/carousel-1-th.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/carousel-2-th.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/carousel-3-th.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/carousel-4-th.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to return the index of the clicked element relative to its parent. So if the user clicked on the second

I would get 1.

///////////////////////////////////////////
Current solution which works but I was hoping to simplify:

```
    //Add a click event to each thumn in the thumbs container
for (var j = 0, len = carouselThumbsContainer.children.length; j < len; j++){
    (function(index){
        carouselThumbsContainer.children[j].onclick = function(){
              console.log(index);
        }    
    })(j);
}
```

Not knowing a ton about Javascript I thought there must be an easier way but perhaps not.

Comment: What do you mean index of the child clicked? you mean its child position? i.e. first child, second child, etc?

Comment: Yes, its child position. The parent is a <ul>, I would like to return the index of the <li> clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (also read: [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/1636522)):

```
carouselThumbsContainer.onclick = function (e) {
    var tgt = e.target, i = 0, items;
    if (tgt === this) return;
    items = children(this);
    while (tgt.parentNode !== this) tgt = tgt.parentNode;
    while (items[i] !== tgt) i++;
    alert(i);
};

function children(el) {
    var i = 0, children = [], child;
    while (child = el.childNodes[i++]) {
        if (child.nodeType === 1) children.push(child);
    }
    return children;
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var hit = false,
    ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
    addButton = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0],
    toggleButton = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1],
    active = null;

ul.onclick = function (e) {
    var i = 0, tgt = e.target, items;
    if (tgt === this) return;
    items = children(ul);
    while (tgt.parentNode !== this) tgt = tgt.parentNode;
    while (items[i] !== tgt) i++;
    hit = true; // for debug purposes only
    if (active) active.className = '';
    (active = tgt).className = 'active';
    output('index : ' + i);
};

addButton.onclick = function () {
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
        n = children(ul).length + 1;
    li.innerHTML = '<a href="#">item ' + n + '</a>';
    li.innerHTML += '<ul><li><a href="#">sub item</a></li></ul>';
    ul.appendChild(li);
    hit = true;
};

toggleButton.onclick = function () {
    ul.className = ul.className ? '' : 'sublists';
    hit = true;
};

document.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (hit) hit = false;
    else output('index : none');
};

// populate the UL

var i = 0;
while (i++ < 5) addButton.onclick();
hit = false;

// helpers

function children(el) {
    var i = 0, children = [], child;
    while (child = el.childNodes[i++]) {
        if (child.nodeType === 1) children.push(child);
    }
    return children;
}

function output(s) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = s;
}
```

```css
body { font-family: Arial; }
div { width: 210px; padding-left: .5em; }
p a { float: right; color: blue; margin-left: .5em; }
ul { border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em 1em 1em 2.5em; }
ul ul { display: none; }
ul.sublists ul { display: block; }
li a { display: block; color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }
li a { border-right: 90px solid transparent; }
li a:hover { border-right-color: blue; }
li.active a { border-right-color: black; }
li li a { border-right-width: 18px; }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
        <a href="#" title="add a new item">add</a>
        <a href="#" title="toggle sub lists">toggle</a>
        <span><i>click any item</i></span>
    </p>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

---

### The click handler line by line

#### The actors

```
var tgt = e.target, i = 0, items; // and `this`
```

`this` is the UL itself. `e.target` is the DOM element that initiated the event. It can be any descendant of the UL or the UL itself (in this case `e.target` = `this`). `i` holds the index of the clicked item. `items` stands for LIs that are direct children of the UL.

#### The story

Exit the function if the target is the UL itself:

```
if (tgt === this) return;
```

Get LIs that are direct children of the UL:

```
items = children(this);
```

Bubble up through target's ancestors until reaching the uppermost LI:

```
while (tgt.parentNode !== this) tgt = tgt.parentNode;
```

Increment the index until the target matches one of the LIs:

```
while (items[i] !== tgt) i++;
```

Alert the index:

```
alert(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can repurpose the array indexOf function and find the index of the target in the parent's children:

```
var el = e.target;
while (el.tagName.toLowerCase() != "li") {
    el = el.parentNode;
}

[].indexOf.call(el.parentNode.children, el);
```

Or just use a for-loop and iterate over `children`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SFke7/2/

Comment: Always get zero when I plugged this is:

    carouselThumbsContainer.onclick = function(e) {
    //var target = ev.target;    // which child was actually clicked
    alert([].indexOf.call(e.target.parentNode.children, e.target));
    }

Comment: Yeah, I realized after you posted the code.  You need to traverse up the tree to get the `li`, then compare it to *its* parent.  Otherwise, you get the index of the `a` element which will always be zero since it is the only element at that level.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Javascript, if you would be kind enough to provide an example that would be awesome.

Comment: Just about there. How can I specify the ul of a specific ID? The fiddle is looking at the first ul instance on the page. In Jquery I would look for the ul with id, not sure how to chain that in Javascript.

Comment: .children only works in IE >= 9. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children

Comment: @JacobLauritzen Good to know. Should have mentioned I needed support for IE7+. I have a solution that works but was looking for something more elegant. Will post my original solution above. Thanks for all the help all.

Comment: @JacobLauritzen `children` works in old-IE as well, according to the link you posted.  Just as long as OP doesn't include comments in the HTML.  `indexOf` is an issue, but can be shimmed.

Comment: @Dennis oh, you're right. About the `indexOf` issue I posted a work-around in my answers comments.

Answer (score 2):

Works for IE >= 9

```
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.children, ev.target);
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/mBg98/

Comment: Shoot, need to support IE7+

Comment: You could add this to your code to make indexOf work in IE:
     
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11473036/1630044

But it might be a bit of an overkill for such a simple task