# IE8 not performing substring within jQuery Address

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-address

Within jQuery Address `target[1]` can be `Films-by-Name-C7`. I use the following to extract `7`

```
(target[1].lastIndexOf('?') > 0 ?target[1].slice(0, target[1].indexOf("?")).substr((target[1].lastIndexOf('C')+1)):target[1].substr(-(target[1].length-target[1].lastIndexOf('C')-1)))
```

This works on all browsers except IE8. I don't know why it does this. When I try it out in  [Fiddle it also doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/zR5NG/2/).  So how can i extract `7` from `Films-by-Name-C7` in ie8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE<9 doesn't have an `.indexOf()` function for Array, to define the exact spec version, run this before trying to use it:

**[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)**

As you need seven 
**[this can be the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/zR5NG/6/)**

Comment: Check the fiddle. There it isn't on an array but on a variable and it still doesn't work.

Comment: .indexOf is not there in IE <9, its not abount for array that can be for variable also....!!

Comment: So there is no way i can extract `7` from `Films-by-Name-C7` then? `alert((typeof test.lastIndexOf('?') !== undefined ?test.slice(0, test.lastIndexOf("?")).substr((test.lastIndexOf('C')+1)):test.substr(-(test.length-test.lastIndexOf('C')-1))));` just gives nothing

Comment: or `alert((testvar.lastIndexOf('?') != "-1" ?testvar.slice(0, testvar.lastIndexOf("?")).substr((testvar.lastIndexOf('C')+1)):testvar.substr(-(testvar.length-testvar.lastIndexOf('C')-1))));` same thing. I guess lastIndexOf isn't supported then as well

Comment: somehow it should be possible to extract `7` from `Films-by-Name-C7` it's the last thing to make this site work for ie8

Comment: but unfortunately a link can-also-be-a-very-long-one-with-many-dashes or a short-one :)

Comment: than buddy.... you need to make some base function that can handle this.... !! :) .... you can user regex and some other option to detect your format and than splitting them.....!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the negative value of `substr` function

```
(target[1].lastIndexOf('?') > 0 ? 
    target[1].slice(0, target[1].indexOf("?")).substr((target[1].lastIndexOf('C')+1)) :
    target[1].substr(-(target[1].length - target[1].lastIndexOf('C')-1)))
```

The negative value of `substr` won't work in browsers < IE9 as per W3C standards

Comment: Depends on your requirement. If your string always ends with the number and you always require the last digit then you can use substr(target[1].length-1,target[1].length)