# IE8 fails on return line of titleCase function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This script that I found on SO seems to be giving IE8 problems. What could the issue with it be?

```
function titleCase (str, glue){
    glue = (glue) ? glue : ['of', 'for', 'and'];
    return str.replace(/(\w)(\w*)/g, function(_, i, r){
        var j = i.toUpperCase() + (r !== null ? r : "");
        return (glue.indexOf(j.toLowerCase())<0)?j:j.toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

It says about the line `return (glue.indexOf(j.toLowerCase())<0)?j:j.toLowerCase();`

> Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Also, it seems to take issue with line 14 of jquery. Which is the very first line that isn't a comment `(function( window, undefined ) {`. But that is when I have it "showing all script errors", so maybe that's just a warning and not really something that's causing it actual problems.

Comment: What data do you give it? And what version of jQuery?

Comment: @mplungjan jquery 1.8.2. Data was just text...ooh..but it was `encodeURIComponent`'d. Would that cause an issue? Aside from that, it's just alphanumeric text.

Comment: Show some please. JSFiddle.net is where to do that

Comment: @mplungjan Even with the `encodeURIComponent` taken off it still fails. Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/inowoc/1/edit) Thanks!

Comment: @mplungjan and I use like this: `for (var c in address_obj){address_obj[c] = titleCase(address_obj[c]);}`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8#3629211

Comment: Use jquery 1.9 and [inarray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: @mplungjan cool, I'll try that. Why jquery 1.9?

Comment: To make sure you tried the latest