# Javascript function doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this function to place some spaces around any text with a slash in it:

```
var startIndex = str.search(">[^<]*/.*</a>");
var index = str.indexOf("/", startIndex);
str = str.substring(0, index) + " / " + str.substring(index + 1);
```

But for some reason it's not working in IE8. Does anyone know how I can change it to work?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you sure the issue does not happen either before or after this piece of code?

Comment: Is that a regex or a string in the search() ???

Comment: @TravisJ - I don't get an error at all, it's just that nothing happens

Comment: @Steven - And it works in chrome? ff?

Comment: Are you trying to regex html?

Comment: @TravisJ - Yes, and it works in IE9

Comment: Ow-ow-ow-ow! Shouldn't it be `/>[^<]*\/.*<\/a>/` instead of string?

Comment: Please see this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8 - IE8 literally does not have indexOf (and many other array-related functions) built-in, but you can add the prototype functions if they are missing on an as-needed basis

Comment: @Matt: `str` is no array, but a string.