# .indexOf() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have created this little interaction for one of the platforms at work - http://jsfiddle.net/S79qp/427/

It works fine in all browsers apart form IE8. When I run the console it seems to be this section that it is having problems with...

```
index = a.indexOf(current) + 1;
if (index < 0 ||  index >= l.length) {
    index = 0;
}
```

Can someone show me an IE8 friendly alternative so I can make it compatible for the versions required?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3629211/803925) provides the polyfill for `indexOf`

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, does it?

Comment: It's a jQuery/JavaScript method @Bergi

Comment: Also, jQuery has a [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray) method which provides this functionality, without mutating the Array prototype

Comment: @Milo-J: It is a native JavaScript method. jQuery is just a JS library, and has nothing to do with this IE8 problem. Yet, jQuery has a utility function to work around the lack of this function: [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: Ok my bad. I have tried the $.inArray function but cannot get it working @Bergi

Answer (score 3):

When you take a look at MDN's [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) Article, You will see that

> indexOf is a recent addition to the ECMA-262 standard; as such it may not be present in all browsers. You can work around this by utilizing the following code at the beginning of your scripts. This will allow you to use indexOf when there is still no native support. This algorithm matches the one specified in ECMA-262, 5th edition, assuming Object, TypeError, Number, Math.floor, Math.abs, and Math.max have their original values.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
        "use strict";
        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            n = Number(arguments[1]);
            if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                n = 0;
            } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
            }
        }
        if (n >= len) {
            return -1;
        }
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        for (; k < len; k++) {
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```