# IE8 Javascript Issues

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The following code works on Chrome, FF and Safari, but not on IE8.

All variables have been tested and are populated.

```
var videoSubTopics = [60,120,240,300];

function function(e) {
   var index = videoSubTopics.indexOf(Math.floor(e.position));
   if (index >= 0) {
       alert(videoSubTopics[index]);
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: IE8 does not have indexof implamentation check this article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8

Comment: How does it not work? Check the error console.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 Arrays does not support the method indexOf

You can refer to this SO Question, and extend the Array Prototype

[Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)

In other words: just add the code of that question answer before your call (maybe at the top of your js file)

```
// the one that starts with: Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

IE8 JScript engine doesn't have indexOf