# equivalent for indexOf() for IE8 and before?

Tags: internet-explorer, indexof

I'm trying to find out how to get the following code in an ajax call to run on IE8 and earlier but I can't seem to find an equivalent to indexOf() that searches more than just one character. I'm trying to replicate

```
    var formKeyLoc = data.indexOf("?f=");
    var tokenLoc = data.indexOf("&token=");
    var endLoc = data.indexOf("'></script>");
```

I've tried inArray() but that seems to only look for one character. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) on mozilla docs. It should be what you need. I'm sorry you are still having to deal with IE8.

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.14
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

    var k;

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing
    //    the this value as the argument.
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    }

    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get
    //    internal method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If len is 0, return -1.
    if (len === 0) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 5. If argument fromIndex was passed let n be
    //    ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be 0.
    var n = +fromIndex || 0;

    if (Math.abs(n) === Infinity) {
      n = 0;
    }

    // 6. If n >= len, return -1.
    if (n >= len) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 7. If n >= 0, then Let k be n.
    // 8. Else, n<0, Let k be len - abs(n).
    //    If k is less than 0, then let k be 0.
    k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

    // 9. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {
      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the
      //    HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      //    i.  Let elementK be the result of calling the Get
      //        internal method of O with the argument ToString(k).
      //   ii.  Let same be the result of applying the
      //        Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to
      //        searchElement and elementK.
      //  iii.  If same is true, return k.
      if (k in O && O[k] === searchElement) {
        return k;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked several times before but here ([Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8?rq=1)) is the polyfill from Mootools:

```
if(!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item, from){
        var length = this.length >>> 0;
        for (var i = (from < 0) ? Math.max(0, length + from) : from || 0; i < length; i++){
            if (this[i] === item) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

There may be nicer ways of doing this depending on the libraries you are using