# How to check for a class name if several classes are assignend?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check for the class name with JS. But as the element has several classes, the used command does not seem to work. How can I check for a single class?

HTML

```
<div class="first_class second_class third_class"> </div>
```

JS

```
var trg = e.target;

if ( trg.classList.contains('third_class') ) {

     console.log(trg);
   }
```

Comment: According to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) it is supposed to work. Are you using an older browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contains` is an underscore method — the native array method it uses is `indexOf` — however neither of these will work because the object returned by `classList` isn't a real array, so we need to apply it to the array's `indexOf` method:

```
if ( Array.prototype.indexOf.call( trg.classList, 'third_class' ) > -1 ) {
    console.log(trg);
}
```

If you *are* using underscore though:

```
if ( _.toArray( trg.classList ).contains( 'third_class' ) ) {
    console.log(trg);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to split the classes into an array and *then* calling indexOf? You will also avoid false positives

Comment: @SamuelBolduc The first method uses an array's method on the array-like list; the second converts the list into an array, then uses a shortcut method (which itself invokes an array method). There's no danger of false positives.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "foo" )
```

Comment: +1. This is what jQuery is good for (i.e. cross-browser support)

Answer (score 1):

*classList* is not currently wiredly available.

Use either *className.indexOf* or *className.split(...)* or get *classList* polyfill: https://github.com/remy/polyfills

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with pure Javascript and avoid third party libraries

```
var trg = e.target;
if (trg.className.split(' ').indexOf('third_class') > -1) {
  console.log(trg);
}
```

If you use `indexOf` on the string directly, you might get false positives (for example, if you search for "foo" and you have a class "foolish" you will get a false positive).

Beware that Internet Explorer < 9 does not support `indexOf`. If you need to support it, either use a [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3629211/1287598) or a method from a third party library like jQuery.

Comment: …but *here*, false *negatives* are possible: when the classes are delimited by any other form of whitespace, this won't catch them. Rather than use string manipulation and or Regex (which could fix this issue), there's less second-guessing involved in using `classList` instead of `className`, since it already knows what the individual classes are.

Comment: I wondered about it while writing it, but I thought "oh well class names are always separated by spaces" ... I still don't know in which case this is not true, but I guess we never know...