# Cannot get indexOf support in IE8 using underscore.js or es5-shim

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, indexof

I am trying to get indexOf to work in IE8, but I cannot seem to get it to happen. I have tried including the es5-shim using:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/2.0.8/es5-shim.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

I also tried using underscore.js. I put that as the first javascript file that is called on the page, but I still get the error in IE8 "Object doesn't support this property or method" when it hits an indexOf() call.

The page I am working on is old and has frames and there is no DOCTYPE declared at the top of the page. Is this why this doesn't work? I have tried adding in a DOCTYPE, but that seems to break all of the formatting of the pages.

Any ideas? What other info do you need? Thanks so much.

Comment: this page might help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8

Comment: Just use the polyfill from [MDN](http://mdn.io/indexOf).

Comment: How are you attempting to use `.indexOf()`? Can you provide an example that demonstrates the error? It's possible the object you're trying to use it with isn't an actual `Array`.

Comment: I am trying to use the [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) plugin for jQuery and it uses the indexOf for some arrays. That site says to include the es5-shim in the page, which I am doing, but I still get the error in IE8. So I was just trying to figure out why that is not working when it works for other sites in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You might also mention what you are trying solve using indexof() as there may be other ways of solving your problem by using different methods that have nothing to do with indexOf().