# IndexOf in IE8 - how to make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, internet-explorer-8, prototype

i've got a problem with an indexOf method in Internet Explorer 8. Places where I use it in my code looks like these above:

1).

```
if ( this.allPlays.indexOf(date.getTime()) !== -1 ) {
```

2).

```
var others = $footer.text().indexOf('CURRENT') >= 0;
```

3).

```
if ( payment.title.indexOf('EURO') >= 0 ) {
```

4).

```
that.music.indexOf(calc.getMusic());
```

How to prepare code, what kind of function use? Array.prototype.indexOf also doesn't work properly.

PS. It's not a native JS, so i can use jQ methods.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3629211/328555 for details. `Array.prototype.indexOf` doesn't exist in IE8.

Comment: Why not using `if ($footer.text() === 'CURRENT')`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) for arrays so you can avoid using the array version of indexOf (not present in IE8).

Two of your other examples are using the string version of [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) which does exist in IE8.