# angular get index of selected item (from ng-options)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the index of the selected item from an ng-options list. I have it in a model but it does not seem to work, I'm unsure what I am doing wrong here.

So I have the ng-options here -

```
<select class="select" ng-model="level.Selection"  ng-options="data for data in dataHere track by data.id"></select>
```

which is bound a model, so right below it, I'm just trying to spit out he index of the selected item like so:

```
<p class="text-left">{{level.Selection.$index}}</p>
```

Can't seem to figuire out what I am doing wrong here. Thanks!!

Comment: level.selection doesn't have a $index because it's your model, you could see the index in a repeater, but once you assign it to the model, the $index is gone. what does {{level.selection}} output?

Comment: You can use select with ng_repeat

Answer (score 0):

What about this?:

```
<p class="text-left">{{dataHere.indexOf(level.Selection)}}</p>
```

As mentioned in the comment bellow, if you want this to work for IE8 (or lower) you may want to have a look at this: [Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)

Comment: indexOf doesn't work in <IE9. Otherwise, it should be fine! You may need to add custom function for indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct markup:

```
<a href="#"> {{attrib.name}}</a>
                <a href="#!/mapping2/info"  ng-show="{{unmapattribute.indexOf(attrib.name)}}!=-1"> Expression</a>
```