# Angular UI Alert does not work on IE 8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Problem,

My alert box works on all the browser except IE 8. It get displayed but does not get closed on click or on timeout. Below is my Code of HTML

```
 <div class="notification">
            <div alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}"  close="alert.close()">{{alert.msg}}</div>
          </div>
```

I have created Services for the alert, so i don't have to duplicate the code. Please let me know if you need my code for alert services.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: We probably need to see the code for the directive/service you created. What you're showing is very generic and there's no sign of what might be the issue in IE8.

Comment: thanks, I found out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some debugging, i found out that indexOf method does not work on IE8 and I was using it. Refer to this post
[Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)