# Remove element from multiple array

Tags: javascript

If I have:

```
var arr = ['2.4.1', 2004001, 'YYY', 'ddd', 'd1'];
```

Then I can remove on value `'2.4.1'`:

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf('2.4.1'), 1);
```

It works, but not in IE7/8.

---

How make for my:

```js
var str = '2.4.1';

var arr = [
['1.1.3', 1001003, 'XXX', 'aaa', 'a3'],
['1.1.1', 1001001, 'XXX', 'aaa', 'a1'],
['1.3.1', 1003001, 'XXX', 'ccc', 'c1'],
['2.4.2', 2004002, 'YYY', 'ddd', 'd2'],
['2.4.1', 2004001, 'YYY', 'ddd', 'd1'],
['1.2.2', 1002002, 'XXX', 'bbb', 'b2'],
['1.2.1', 1002001, 'XXX', 'bbb', 'b1'],
];


arr.splice(4, 1);
//         ^_____ How to receive this index on my value '2.4.1' ?
//   Help to make cross browser and without JQuery, please.
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8

Comment: If you're not keen on polyfill, it's more code but you can fetch, identify the correct key with a regexp, and then delete it.

Comment: When you say "remove" you mean "delete" a value from the array or just copy it?

Comment: "remove" -> delete key and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE < 9 doesn't 'know' `Array.indexOf`, so you'll need a polyfill for it. You can find that [**@MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill)

You can also use `Array.filter` to remove the array containing '2.4.1' (see snippet):

```
arr = arr.filter( function (v) { return v[0] !== '2.4.1'; } );
```

For IE < 9 you need [**this polyfill**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill).

```js
// check for presence of Array.filter and if necessary add it
polyfills();

// declarations
var str = '2.4.1';
var arr = [
  ['1.1.3', 1001003, 'XXX', 'aaa', 'a3'],
  ['1.1.1', 1001001, 'XXX', 'aaa', 'a1'],
  ['1.3.1', 1003001, 'XXX', 'ccc', 'c1'],
  ['2.4.2', 2004002, 'YYY', 'ddd', 'd2'],
  ['2.4.1', 2004001, 'YYY', 'ddd', 'd1'],
  ['1.2.2', 1002002, 'XXX', 'bbb', 'b2'],
  ['1.2.1', 1002001, 'XXX', 'bbb', 'b1'],
];
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

// show original  
result.innerHTML = '<code>arr</code> initially:<br>' +
                   arr.map( function (v) { return v.join(); } ).join('<br>');

// remove using filter
arr = removesub(arr, str);
  
// show array after removal
result.innerHTML += '<hr><code>arr</code> after removing:<br>'+
                     arr.map( function (v) { return v.join(); } ).join('<br>');

  // removal function
function removesub(arr2RemoveFrom, str2Remove) {
  arr2RemoveFrom = arr2RemoveFrom.filter( 
                    function (v) { return v[0] !== str2Remove; } 
                   );
  return arr2RemoveFrom;
}
  

function polyfills() {
  // source MDN. Removed.comments
  if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var res = [];
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t) {
        var val = t[i];
        if (fun.call(thisArg, val, i, t)) {
          res.push(val);
        }
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
 }
  
 if (!Array.prototype.map) {

  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    var O = Object(this);
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
 
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    A = new Array(len);
    k = 0;

    while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;
      if (k in O) {
        kValue = O[k];
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return A;
  };
 }
}
```

```css
code {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I looked 'polyfill' earlier but could not fasten to my case.

Comment: Hi @Alex, see modified answer for an alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first value as a key, using a hash of arrays instead of a array of arrays and use the method [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Something like this:

```
var str = '2.4.1';

var arr = {
  '1.1.3': ['1.1.3', 1001003, 'XXX', 'aaa', 'a3'],
  '1.1.1': ['1.1.1', 1001001, 'XXX', 'aaa', 'a1'],
  '1.3.1': ['1.3.1', 1003001, 'XXX', 'ccc', 'c1'],
  '2.4.2': ['2.4.2', 2004002, 'YYY', 'ddd', 'd2'],
  '2.4.1': ['2.4.1', 2004001, 'YYY', 'ddd', 'd1'],
  '1.2.2': ['1.2.2', 1002002, 'XXX', 'bbb', 'b2'],
  '1.2.1': ['1.2.1', 1002001, 'XXX', 'bbb', 'b1']
};


delete arr[str];
```

Comment: After remove there are inserts elements and array sorting (by 1001001 ... ) So I can not to make. Thanks. Good idea.