# IE8 JS error -- object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using the custom ExtJS "treecombo", works fine in FF and Chrome but sucks in IE. I am using IE8. Here is the code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.plugins.TreeCombo',
{
  extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',
  alias: 'widget.treecombo',
  tree: false,
  constructor: function(config)
  {
    this.addEvents(
    {
      "itemclick" : true
    });


    this.listeners = config.listeners;
    this.callParent(arguments);
  },
  records: [],
  recursiveRecords: [],
  ids: [],
  selectChildren: true,
  canSelectFolders: true,
  multiselect: false,
  displayField: 'text',
  valueField: 'text',
  treeWidth: 300,
  matchFieldWidth: false,
  treeHeight: 400,
  masN: 0,
  recursivePush: function(node, setIds)
  {
    var me = this;


    me.addRecRecord(node);
    if(setIds) me.addIds(node);

    node.eachChild(function(nodesingle)
    {
      if(nodesingle.hasChildNodes() == true)
      {
        me.recursivePush(nodesingle, setIds);
      }
      else
      {
        me.addRecRecord(nodesingle);
        if(setIds) me.addIds(nodesingle);
      }
    });
  },
  recursiveUnPush: function(node)
  {
    var me = this;
    me.removeIds(node);

    node.eachChild(function(nodesingle)
    {
      if(nodesingle.hasChildNodes() == true)
      {
        me.recursiveUnPush(nodesingle);
      }
      else me.removeIds(nodesingle);
    });
  },
  addRecRecord: function(record)
  {
    var me = this;


    for(var i=0,j=me.recursiveRecords.length;i<j;i++)
    {
      var item = me.recursiveRecords[i];
      if(item)
      {
        if(item.getId() == record.getId()) return;
      }
    }
    me.recursiveRecords.push(record);
  },
  afterLoadSetValue: false,
  setValue: function(valueInit)
  {
    if(typeof valueInit == 'undefined') return;

    var me = this,
      tree = this.tree,
      values = (valueInit == '') ? [] : valueInit.split(','),
      valueFin = [];

    inputEl = me.inputEl;


    if(tree.store.isLoading())
    {
      me.afterLoadSetValue = valueInit;
    }


    if(inputEl && me.emptyText && !Ext.isEmpty(values))
    {
      inputEl.removeCls(me.emptyCls);
    }


    if(tree == false) return false;

    var node = tree.getRootNode();
    if(node == null) return false;

    me.recursiveRecords = [];
    me.recursivePush(node, false);

    me.records = [];
    Ext.each(me.recursiveRecords, function(record)
    {
      var id = record.get(me.valueField);          
      var index = values.indexOf(''+id);

      if(me.multiselect == true) record.set('checked', false);

      if(index != -1)
      {
        valueFin.push(record.get(me.displayField));
        if(me.multiselect == true) record.set('checked', true);
        me.addRecord(record);
      }
    });


    me.value = valueInit;
    me.setRawValue(valueFin.join(', '));

    me.checkChange();
    me.applyEmptyText();
    return me;
  },
  getValue: function() 
  {
    return this.value;
  },
  getSubmitValue: function()
  {
    return this.value;
  },
  checkParentNodes: function(node)
  {
    if(node == null) return;

    var me = this,
      checkedAll = true;


    node.eachChild(function(nodesingle)
    {
      var id = nodesingle.getId(),
        index = me.ids.indexOf(''+id);

      if(index == -1) checkedAll = false;
    });

    if(checkedAll == true)
    {
      me.addIds(node);
      me.checkParentNodes(node.parentNode);
    }
    else
    {
      me.removeIds(node);
      me.checkParentNodes(node.parentNode);
    }
  },
  initComponent: function() 
  {
    var me = this;

    me.tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',
    {
      alias: 'widget.assetstree',
      hidden: true,
      minHeight: 300,
      rootVisible: (typeof me.rootVisible != 'undefined') ? me.rootVisible : true,
      floating: true,
      useArrows: true,
      width: me.treeWidth,
      autoScroll: true,
      height: me.treeHeight,
      store: me.store,
      listeners:
      {
        load: function(store, records)
        {
          if(me.afterLoadSetValue != false)
          {
            me.setValue(me.afterLoadSetValue);
          }
        },
        itemclick:  function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts)
        {
          me.itemTreeClick(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, me)
        }
      }
    });

    if(me.tree.getRootNode().get('checked') != null) me.multiselect = true;

    this.createPicker = function()
    {
      var me = this;
      return me.tree;
    };

    this.callParent(arguments);
  },
  addIds: function(record)
  {
    var me = this;

    if(me.ids.indexOf(''+record.getId()) == -1) me.ids.push(''+record.get(me.valueField));
  },
  removeIds: function(record)
  {
    var me = this,
      index = me.ids.indexOf(''+record.getId());

    if(index != -1)
    {
      me.ids.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  addRecord: function(record)
  {
    var me = this;


    for(var i=0,j=me.records.length;i<j;i++)
    {
      var item = me.records[i];
      if(item)
      {
        if(item.getId() == record.getId()) return;
      }
    }
    me.records.push(record);
  },
  removeRecord: function(record)
  {
    var me = this;


    for(var i=0,j=me.records.length;i<j;i++)
    {
      var item = me.records[i];
      if(item && item.getId() == record.getId()) delete(me.records[i]);
    }
  },
  itemTreeClick: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, treeCombo)
  {

    var me = treeCombo,
      checked = !record.get('checked');//it is still not checked if will be checked in this event

    if(me.multiselect == true) record.set('checked', checked);//check record

    var node = me.tree.getRootNode().findChild(me.valueField, record.get(me.valueField), true);
    me.setValue(record.data.text);
    if(node == null) 
    {
      if(me.tree.getRootNode().get(me.valueField) == record.get(me.valueField)) node = me.tree.getRootNode();
      else return false;
    }

    if(me.multiselect == false) me.ids = [];

    //if it can't select folders and it is a folder check existing values and return false
    if(me.canSelectFolders == false && record.get('leaf') == false)
    {
      me.setRecordsValue(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, treeCombo);
      return false;
    }

    //if record is leaf
    if(record.get('leaf') == true) 
    {
      if(checked == true)
      {
        me.addIds(record);
      }
      else
      {
        me.removeIds(record);
      }
    }
    else //it's a directory
    {     
      me.recursiveRecords = [];
      if(checked == true)
      {
        if(me.multiselect == false)
        {
          if(me.canSelectFolders == true) me.addIds(record); 
        }
        else
        {
          if(me.canSelectFolders == true)
          {
            me.recursivePush(node, true);
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if(me.multiselect == false)
        {
          if(me.canSelectFolders == true) me.recursiveUnPush(node);
          else me.removeIds(record);
        }
        else me.recursiveUnPush(node);
      }
    }

    //this will check every parent node that has his all children selected
    if(me.canSelectFolders == true && me.multiselect == true) me.checkParentNodes(node.parentNode);

    me.setRecordsValue(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, treeCombo);
  },
  fixIds: function()
  {
    var me = this;

    for(var i=0,j=me.ids.length;i<j;i++)
    {
      if(me.ids[i] == 'NaN') me.ids.splice(i, 1);
    }
  },
  setRecordsValue: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, treeCombo)
  {
    var me = treeCombo;

    me.fixIds();

    me.setValue(me.ids.join(','));


    me.fireEvent('itemclick', me, record, item, index, e, eOpts, me.records, me.ids);


    if(me.multiselect == false) me.onTriggerClick();
  } 
});
```

I am getting Object doesnt support this property or method on line 116:

```
var index = values.indexOf(''+id);
```

anybody have any ideas??

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` is introduced in ECMAScript 5, and it is not supported on IE before version 9.

Comment: Something similar JUST affected me. Turned out to be that I can't say "var item = " in javascript in IE8 as "item" is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because IE8 doesn't have an `indexOf()` method for arrays. You'll have to include a polyfill. Take a look at **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)** for an example.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```