# SAP UI5 table export

Tags: sapui5, hana

I am trying to export my SAP UI5 table data to csv file using following function,

```
           table_export = oTable.exportData();
            table_export.saveFile('MY');
```

also tried,

```
   oTable.exportData().saveFile('MY');
```

But I am getting the following error

```
      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexof' of undefined
```

Someone could help me with the error

BR- Sathish

Comment: I guess your error comes from something else, it should work just fine... have you imported the `Export` and `ExportTypeCSV` classes in your page?

Comment: Also, have you specified the `exportType` in the `exportData()` call? See https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/f1ee7a8b2102415bb0d34268046cd3ea.html for an example.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the reply. Yes i saw the above link and already have the classes included. and i have defined my export type as ExportTypeCSV()... but again i am getting the same error. I found one more link  https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/relnotes/ReleaseNotes-1.24.html .. may be its due to version.. but not sure.. .

Comment: I have managed to export the files using some available codes using data URI schema functionality, it works fine but in IE 8.. :(.. You guys have any idea .. i am opening another post for this..

Comment: For older browsers, there are some clever hacks. One of them is to create a iFrame programmatically and download the file.

Comment: Pretty sure you are calling "indexof" instead of "indexOf" somewhere in your code. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: simple answer IE8 is not supported by ui5. you must fetch data by yourself from the model and build some csv file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8

Answer (score 0):

On click off button you can download your table in excel format

```
new sap.m.Button({
    icon:"sap-icon://download",
    type:"Emphasized",
    press: function(oEvent) {
        debugger;

        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.util.Export");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV");

        oTable.exportData({

        }).saveFile()
        .always(function() {
            this.destroy();
        });
```

while defining your table columns, mention the below properties too.

```
sortProperty: "approved_on",
filterProperty: "approved_on"
```

Note: "approved_on" is the value binded to the respective column.

Comment: jQuery.sap.require is deprecated: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.require

Answer (score 0):

The solution is available here how to download data of table into a CSV file.
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableExport/code/Table.controller.js

You have to Import Export and ExportTypeCSV at the top from the libraries.
This works good and I have used the same code in my project app as well. I Hope this is much more simpler.