# JavaScript method parameter rationalization

Tags: javascript

I just read some code: [Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

I'be been writing JavaScript for years now, and i have never seen parameters handled like this before.

```
elt, /*, from*/
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.prototype.indexOf` has a required argument `searchElement` and an optional one `fromIndex`.

Usually the `length` property shouldn't count optional arguments, but if the polyfill used `function(elt, from)` then the `length` would be `2`.

```
var f1 = function(a, b) {},
    f2 = function(a /*,b*/) {};
f1.length; // 2
f2.length; // 1
```

So my guess is that it's commented to make sure `Array.prototype.indexOf.length` is `1`, as dictated by the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14):

> The `length` property of the `indexOf` method is 1.

Note commenting it does not limit its functionality because it is still accessible through `arguments[1]`.

It could also be remove (comments are ignored). However, having it as a comment can be helpful for authors.

Comment: is this rendered the same on all browsers? i find it 'odd' that it would count a comment in the length

Comment: @user2712605 Precisely, commented arguments are ignored, and thus not counted.

Answer (score 1):

All functions in Javascript have an implicit "arguments" parameter. The commented `/*from*/` isn't doing anything, but the author clearly is trying to give a heads up that you can pass another parameter to this function. You can see down below where they read the parameter: `var from = Number(arguments[1]);`

Here's a reference: https://github.com/iteles/Javascript-the-Good-Parts-notes#arguments