# indexOf not working despite value is present in array

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple script to check if the array contains a link.
here is my code:-

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSPg');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Referral Forms');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange("L1:L" + lastrow).getDisplayValues();  
  
  var index = data.indexOf(arr.link);

  Logger.log(arr.link)    
  Logger.log(data)
  Logger.log(" index:"+index)
```

My log shows value is present but its index is showing `-1`.
One thing I noticed that my value contains special characters can that be the reason?

here is a snapshot of my logs:-

[image]

Comment: whats your expected output ?

Comment: my expected out is index = 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why indexOf in javascript not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851903/why-indexof-in-javascript-not-working)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping This doesn't seem to be anything like that question.

Comment: @Barmar the question is about `indexOf`

Comment: Problem is that second variable in array has array type with one element equal your link, but the first variable has a string type

Comment: There are lots of questions about indexOf, they're not all the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is a 2-dimensional array. Every element is an array, but `arr.link` is a string.

You can use `map()` to unwrap the strings from the arrays.

```
data = sheet.getRange("L1:L" + lastrow).getDisplayValues().map(x => x[0]);
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851903/why-indexof-in-javascript-not-working)

Comment: They don't seem to be at all alike to me.