# RobinHerbots' jQuery Inputmask not working on IE8 (WinXP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, jquery-inputmask

My scenario: I'm trying to mask some input fields using jQuery Inputmask Plugin. It is ok on Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE10, Firefox, but not on IE8!

I created a dummy page to test if other scripts was interfering, but isn't the case.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputmask/inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputmask/inputmask.dependencyLib.jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputmask/inputmask.phone.extensions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputmask/inputmask.regex.extensions.js"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie8customscripts.js"></script>
    <link href="css/ie8customstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie9customscripts.js"></script>
    <link href="css/ie9customstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    cpf<br/><input id="cpf" type="text"></input>
    cnpj<br/><input id="cnpj" type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS (ie8customscripts.js)**

```
$(function(){  
   $("#cpf").inputmask("99-9999999");  //static mask
   $("#cnpj").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"}); //specifying options
});
```

In my actual pages, i was using `data-` attributes to set the mask, which obviously didn't worked on IE8, so i tried to do this way.

Here's the exact line that throws the error (it is thrown about 20 times).

[image: inputmaskerror]

Until where I know, it was supposed to work on IE8, right?

Comment: IE8 support should be forbidden in 2016...

Comment: @JeremyThille Agreed! I wish the enterprises think like you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 and below doesn't support `indexOf`. You can polyfill it yourself, but you are modifying the prototype of a native object and that's super shiesty. But hey, that's the name of the game with IE.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

credit: @NickCraver
[Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)

Comment: Nice one @Antiga! Only a doubt, can this wreak havoc in any situation with IE8?

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos well, the first conditional is checking if there is already an `indexOf` function on `Array`, so it's pretty safe. I would never recommend modifying a native object like this, but you don't really have another option. That's IE8.

Comment: Understood! Really, no option, IE8 needs cheating to work properly. Man you just saved hours and hours of more head-banging stress, i spent half of a day in this trouble. Thanks A LOT!!!!

Comment: Happy to help and apologies that you have to deal with IE8. I wouldn't wish that on my worst enemy. Let your stakeholders know that `<IE10` is losing support from Microsoft this next Tuesday. :)

Comment: LOL nice to know! I'll tell them today! Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which version of jQuery and jquery.inputmask do you use but I had the same trouble yesterday with jQuery 1.8.3 and jquery.inputmask 3.3.x version running on IE8. So I did some investigation on jquery.inputmask and I have realized that it relies on jQuery.inArray method feeding both with string and array parameters as well. I have checked jQuery 1.8.3, 1.10.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.4 versions as well and the situation was exactly the same.

Here is the jQuery implementation of it's inArray method:

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    var len;

    if ( arr ) {
        if ( Array.prototype.indexOf ) {
            return Array.prototype.indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
        }

        len = arr.length;
        i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            // Skip accessing in sparse arrays
            if ( i in arr && arr[ i ] === elem ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
},
```

Yo can see if the Array.prototype.indexOf exists the native implementation will be executed. So there is no problem when IE11, Chrome, Firefox because they have native implementation for Array.prototype.indexOf which is missing from IE8.

So in IE8 this part of code will be executed:

```
        len = arr.length;
        i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            // Skip accessing in sparse arrays
            if ( i in arr && arr[ i ] === elem ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
```

this code does the same thing what Antiga suggested - so in your code you would use $.inArray as well

But calling inArray with string parameters (as jquery.inputmask does) instead of array cause exception at the **i in arr** line that in operation is invalid for string. **That is why I have used the following override (after including jquery.js of course) in my application** (at my company IE8 is still used):

```
$.inArray = function (elem, arr, i) {
    var len;
    if (arr) {
        if (typeof arr === "string") {
            // this is my extension
            return arr.indexOf(elem, i);
        } else {
            if (Array.prototype.indexOf) {
                return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(arr, elem, i);
            }
            len = arr.length;
            i = i ? (i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i) : 0;
            for (; i < len; i++) {
                // Skip accessing in sparse arrays
                if (i in arr && arr[ i ] === elem) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

This solved all of the problem related to jQuery 1.8+, jquery.inputmask 3.3.x and IE8 cooperation.

Comment: Thank you, been searching through the end of the Internet for this.