# Most efficient way to find if array contains specific element

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-11

I need a function that returns true/false if the array contains specific element or not.
There are some functions such:

```
arr.includes(element)
```

that is not support IE 11.

```
arr.some(el => el === element)
arr.filter(el => el === element)[0]
```

that are supported IE 11.

But what are the best solution? Is there any more efficient way for instance by using binary search? Or any of those work with approximately perfect efficient? Any little contribution for efficient with wider browser support is attractive.

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308396/how-to-polyfill-array-prototype-includes-for-ie8

Comment: All of these will do a linear scan through the array. So, the time complexity will be the same. The runtime may differ but I'd wager not by much. Well, `.filter()` will do a *full* scan while `includes`/`indexOf`/`some` can finish early but still.

Comment: `some` stops iterating once found, `filter` iterates over all elements, always. So between `some` and `filter`, use `some`. Not sure you'll find much better.

Comment: At any rate, this is very relevant: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You cannot use binary search unless you know that the array is sorted.

Comment: Sort the array and then use a simple `for...loop` to check the elements, breaking out of the loop if an element matches.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for IE 11 :

```
function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is better than `some` ?

Comment: Because `indexOf` faster than `some`, you can see in here https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2554/0/some-vs-filter-vs-indexof