# How to fix 'indexof' in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I don't know how to fix the     indexof as it is bringing error ("object doesn't support this property or method".) in IE8 on win xp

```
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var classes = x.className.split(" ");
var i = classes.indexOf("mystyle");

if (i >= 0) 
  classes.splice(i, 1);
else 
  classes.push("mystyle");
  x.className = classes.join(" ");
```

Comment: It shouldn't produce an error. What do you actually get?

Comment: I'm sorry, i've just edited the question, the error is "object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Doesn't sound like it should come from `indexOf`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as is WinXP...

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8) should help.

Comment: `indexOf` is only available from IE9 onwards. You could of course find a polyfill

Comment: Side note: I strongly recommend using `{}`, and being careful with indentation. Your code is indented as though you only wrote back to `x.className` in the `else`. That isn't true (and it's correct that it isn't true), but the indentation and lack of `{}` make it misleading.

Comment: @VLAZ - Same answer, XP is seriously out of date and I don't think it's receiving security patches anymore. But even on XP, use Chromium, not IE8.

Comment: I just verified it with an old VM, IE8 didn't have `Array.prototype.indexOf`. Wow.

Comment: I wanted to create a dropdown menu but the HTML Compiler i want to use is not supporting this   `document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");` So i don't know which way to go

Comment: I suggest you can try to use the polyfill provided in this documentation link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf It may help to solve your issue. The IE 8 and Win XP is too old and out of support scope of Microsoft. I suggest you try to use at least IE 11 version.