# Replace value of an element in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. If I do a console.log, I see this data.

```
[Object,Object,Object]
0: Object
  Name: Ria
  Age: 27
  Job: Analytics & Review

1: Object
  Name: Brian
  Age: 23
  Job: Admin

2: Object
  Name: Rick
  Age: 32
  Job: Analytics & Review
```

As you can see at the Job part, I have & symbol. I want to replace that & with `&amp;` since html does not allow & to pass directly through ajax since its a reserved entity.

Can someone let me know how I can replace & with `&amp;` wherever they exist.

Comment: sorry, we cant see what you want to replace & with (you'll have to put it in the grave marks ` so we can see it), and what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807180/how-to-escape-a-json-string-to-have-it-in-a-url

Comment: can you provide sample how you want use this object, and show why `&` should be encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it

```
var data = [{ Name: 'Ria', Age: 27, Job: 'Analytics & Review'}, 
            { Name: 'Brian',  Age: 23,  Job: 'Admin'}, 
            { Name: 'Rick', Age: 32, Job: 'Analytics & Review'}]; 

data.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array) { 
    array[index] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array[index]).replace('&', '&amp')); 
});
```

Comment: why needed `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(`?

Comment: @Grundy because of replace method... you can use replace only with strings. If you want to replace '&' wherever they exist, you have to do it with strings. After that, you need to parse string in to json and replace old object in array.

Comment: so, why not just convert to string if needed, or even do replace if `currentValue` is srting?

Comment: @Grundy `currentValue` is not a string. It is an object. To convert object to string needed use `JSON.stringify` method. You can use `currentValue` instead `array[index]` it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to `convert your entire array of object into string` and then `use regex to replace the symbol` and then parse back the array of objects back from the string. Try this.

`var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array).replace(/&/g,'&amp'));`