# Old IE JavaScript doesn't support indexOf

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

From input file type i am passing fullPath(entire local path name)  to javascript , and i have written javascript to know the file extension type ,

```
 while (fullPath.indexOf("\\") != -1)
            fullPath = fullPath.slice(file.indexOf("\\") + 1);
        alert(fullPath);
```

I have problem in IE only at above part , exactly i found indexOf is not supported in IE, how may i alter my this . If that is not the case is there any alternate to know the file extension which can work in all browsers.

thanks,
michaeld

Comment: For a thorough explanation of the issue as well as a work around not only for indexOf but the other missing array functions in IE check out the StackOverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc

Answer (score 6):

You could create it ([Javascript Code to create method](http://www.pearweb.com/javascript/array-index-of.html))

For ease of use:

```
if(!Array.indexOf){
   Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
       for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
          if(this[i]==obj){ 
             return i; 
          }
       } 
       return -1; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: hi steve looked it but not clear how to add into the code , but solved it in my code other way. thank you!!!

Comment: While this is a suitable, simple replacement, the MDN has a more robust polyfill which is ECMA compliant. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf()` *is* supported in IE, at least as far back as version 3.0, assuming you are trying to use it on *strings*. I believe support for `indexOf()` on *arrays* was finally added in IE9.

The example you include in your question is using `indexOf()` on variables called `fullPath` and `file`, which I would assume are strings, but why are you mixing up a while condition on the index within `fullpath` with a slice operation that uses the index within `file`:

```
while (fullPath.indexOf("\\") != -1)
  fullPath = fullPath.slice(file.indexOf("\\") + 1);
// what is the file variable ^^
```

To work out the file type you want all the characters after the last ".", so try using the [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) function:

```
var fileType = fullPath.slice(fullPath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

(Add your own else case for when there is no "." in the string.)

As an aside, I wouldn't assume that the filesystem uses the "\" character to separate folder names: what about non-Windows systems?