# Optimize OR in IF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this:

```
if (action == 'John' || action == 'John Beckham' || action == 'Henry John'){
     alert('true!');
}
```

How do I minimize this code?

Should work in IE7.

Comment: It's hard to see where your stuck here. What did you try? Where are you struggling?

Comment: You could remove the spaces ;-) and use a variable `a` instead of `action`...

Comment: You original question text was more clear than the current phrasing. It provided an example of what you wanted to achieve, which was checking set membership instead of checking each possible value directly (`action ∈ [a,b,c]` instead of `action == a || action == b ...)`

Comment: I've updated it, because action is always different but may consist of the same words in different direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If "John" always appears, the simplest thing is:

```
if (action.toLowerCase().indexOf("john") !== -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

...but as your question has already changed the values against which you're checking `action` once, I hesitate to assume that. Also note that it will match "xxxjohnxxx", which may not be what you want.

Original suggestions (updated for new `action` values from your edit):

---

There are lots of ways, all shown using case **in**sensitivity since you mentioned that in the comments:

`String#indexOf`:

```
if ("|john|john beckham|john henry|giggs john|scholes john|john messi|".indexOf("|" + action.toLowerCase() + "|") !== -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

---

Regular expressions:

```
if (/^(?:John|John Beckham|John Henry|Giggs John|Scholes John|John Messi)$/i.test(action)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Because you're just using the true/false result, I'm using [`test`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3) which just returns true/false, instead of [`exec`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) which returns matching results. Both work in this case, but the browser may be able to ever-so-slightly optimize `test` (but then, regex is unlikely to be the best solution if your goal is the fastest result or the least memory use).

---

Or a `switch`:

```
switch (action.toLowerCase()) {
    case "john":
    case "john beckham":
    case "john henry":
    case "giggs john":
    case "scholes john":
    case "john messi":
        // Do something
}
```

---

Or an object lookup:

```
var actions = {
    "john":         true,
    "john beckham": true,
    "john henry":   true,
    "giggs john":   true,
    "scholes john": true,
    "john messi":   true
};

if (actions[action.toLowerCase()]) {
    // do something
}
```

*(That also has the advantage of letting you say* what *to do — e.g., the `true` could be replaced with a function you call.)*

---

Or (on an ES5-enabled environment or with an ES5 shim) `Array#indexOf`:

```
if (["john", "john beckham", "john henry", "giggs john", "scholes john", "john messi"].indexOf(action.toLowerCase()) !== -1 {
    // Do something
}
```

or since you use jQuery, you can avoid the shim on older browsers by using [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
if ($.inArray(action.toLowerCase(), ["john", "john beckham", "john henry", "giggs john", "scholes john", "john messi"]) !== -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: The regex (horrible solution) can be sortened to `[a-g]` and it would be a good idea to have a `default` in that switch

Comment: I've updated a question, none of the examples in your code would work.

Comment: @Griffin: I was giving the OP lots of choices. Re the switch, a `default` is fine, but not necessary, as there was no `else` shown in the question.

Comment: The only way to optimize this seems to be a one line regexp

Comment: only switch will work, but it's huge. indexof can't be used because of ie7.

Comment: @Steve: No, most of them still apply, not just `switch`. Updated with examples.

Comment: @T.J very good answer but because of cut cut its not looking good. I feel you should remove that part

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And you can see magic as you remove you will get +1 :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd vote this +1 if the author removes everything but `$.inArray`, which is the only one that actually answers the Q

Comment: $.inArray seems to be a slower solution than regexp

Comment: @OneTrickPony: Why is it the only one that answers the question? All of the others are also valid, useful approaches. And offer more to work with should a similar thing come up for him in the future, but where he needs (say) the further information the object lookup can give him.

Comment: @Steve: When editing, I forgot to remove the `[]`. Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/CqxcA/3/

Comment: works now, thanks. Any chance to make it work for both `John` and `john`?

Comment: @Steve: Add the `i` flag: `/John|John Messi/i.test(...)`

Comment: @Steve Sorry, but this regexp will hurt you if you have names with extra chars at the start or end: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CqxcA/4/

Comment: @Steve: Turns out all of my original solutions applied, I've added back the `String#indexOf` option (the only one I actually removed). I'm not saying I'd use it, just saying it's an option. :-)

Answer (score 3):

if using jquery, then you could do:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
if( $.inArray(action, arr) !== -1 ) {
  alert("true");
}
```

Comment: This is the best way, since it will use native `indexOf` if available in modern browsers, and does not require shim for IE7.

Comment: Almost the best answer, because OP tagged this with jQuery, but `$.inArray` may return 0 if the action is the first element in the array, and that evaluates to false. You should check if < 0 (-1)

Comment: what about a regex like `/one|two|three|four|five/`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it uses [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp):

```
if (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].indexOf(action) > -1) {
  alert(true);
}
```

Update: If you want to support IE7 and below, use [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829101/old-ie-javascript-doesnt-support-indexof)

If you're using jQuery, you can use [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) like this:

```
if ($.inArray(action, ['a','b','c','d') > -1) {
  alert(true);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use a regexp with [`test`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) (The group makes the regexp not match `"John Langhammerer"` / actions with extra chars to the ones to be matched):

```
if ((/^(John Langhammer|Piet Krauthammer|Some Guy)$/i).test(action)) {
  alert(true);
}
```

**UPDATE**: `/i` makes the regexp case insensitive.

*Below is a solution which would have worked for one-char actions:*

You can also use [String.indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) which is supported in IE7 (if your actions are all one char):

```
if ('abcde'.indexOf(action) > -1) {
  alert(true);
}
```

Comment: ie 7 doesn't support indexOf (op mentioned ie 7 support)

Comment: ie7 supports indexof, but only for strings

Comment: @OneTrickPony true, added how to add a shim.

Comment: Adding a shim to support one line of code seems to be a messy solution

Comment: It's unlikely that all actions are present in the string, considering the OPs condition. And check out the edit :)

Comment: @steve It will just be messy as long as IE7 is around. If using jQuery, the shim is already included. Edited the answer

Comment: @OneTrickPony thats why my answer reads *if your actions are all one char*.

Comment: I've previously seen people using regex like `/one|two|three|four|five/`, it's a short solution for `or`. Can you code it?

Comment: are you sure this regex is a right one? what about starting and ending  points

Comment: @Steve you did not take my regexp. [Mine goes like this](http://jsfiddle.net/CqxcA/1/)

Comment: @steve, sure, use `/i` at the end of the regexp. It makes the regexp match case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array as below.

```
var newAry = array('a','b','c');
```

Now just check it as below.

```
$(function()
{
    var newAry = Array('a','b','c');
    if($.inArray(action,newAry)){ alert(action); }
});
```

Comment: @OneTrickPony stefan sorry for my bad i just added too quickly.

Comment: @OneTrickPony see i have updated code...Thanx for quick response about mistake +1 for u too

Answer (score 1):

Cross-browser solution:

```
if ( action in {'John':1, 'John Beckham':1, 'John Henry':1, 'Giggs John':1, 'Scholes John':1, 'John Messi':1 } ){
     alert('true!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of `indexOf`, you can also use conditional operator in Javascript.

```
names = ['John' , 
         'John Beckham', 
         'John Henry' , 
         'Giggs John' , 
         'Scholes John', 
         'John Messi'
];
names.indexOf(action) != -1? alert('True') : alert ('False');
```

And you want to do more then simple statement do like:

```
 names.indexOf(action) != -1? doSomethingOnTrue() : doSomethingOnFalse();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if('abcdefg'.indexOf(action) > -1){
    // action is one of 'abcdef'
}
```