# Exact matching using regexp

Tags: javascript

```
var name ='John Rock';
alert((/^John|Steve$/i).test(name));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/czBhb/

This code alerts `true`, because doesn't use an exact mathing, but has to.

Should return `true` for `John` and `joHn` (case matching off). But not for `John 12` or `mahjohng`.

There is `|` in the code, we should keep it.

How do I fix this regexp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - Match whole string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6298566/851811).

Comment: Apparently `|` has lower operator precedence than `^` and `$`, which is a little counterintuitive.  So you need to wrap `John|Steve` in parentheses, in order to apply the `|` before the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: I already pointed out how to do this in [my answer to your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15066690/157247) more than half an hour ago, as soon as Beat Richartz pointed out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
var name ='John Rock';
alert((/^(John|Steve)$/i).test(name));
```

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to match *exactly* `John` or `Steve`, you want to put a group in there:

```
alert(/^(?:John|Steve)$/i.text(name));
```

Also note the `i` for case insensitivity. (I did point this out in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15066690/157247) more than half an hour ago, as soon as Beat Richartz pointed out the problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alert(/^(?:John|Steve)$/i).test(name))
```

`(?:` groups between `^` and `$` without actually creating the group

`/i` for the case insensitivity

Answer (score 1):

The point is in the `^` and `$` delimiters. As already pointed out in the comments, they seem to have precedence over the OR, so your regex is matching anything that starts with `John`, or ends with `Steve`.

Put the delimiters outside the OR:

```
var name ='John Rock';
alert((/^(John|Steve)$/).test(name));
```