# Apache - Can I make a proxy server with just Apache?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, cross-domain, xss

I have a bunch of subdomains in one single server:

- a.example.com
- b.example.com
- news.example.com

All of them are in the same Apache virtualhost.

I need to use a feed provided by the news subdomain inside the a and b subdomain. The feeds typically look like this:

- news.example.com/news/a
- news.example.com/news/b

On the a and b subdomains, I'm using [jquery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to load the data from the news feeds, and present it on a and b. This initially didn't work, because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

I was able to override this by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to my Apache config file.

... but this works only in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Internet explorer seems to ignore that directive.

Thus, I need to create a proxy.

What I need is a new directory in all my subcomains (for example `/proxy`) that Apache detects, and redirects to news.example.com, no matter what the subdomain. So:

- a.example.com/proxy/news/a -> return the contents of news.example.com/news/a
- b.example.com/proxy/news/b -> return the contents of news.example.com/news/b

Can I do this directly in Apache + submodules (for example, mod_rewrite), or do I need to use a scripting language like PHP for doing this?

Comment: See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors) for some links to documentation on getting CORS to work in IE8+

Comment: Kudos for actually knowing about example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end we were able to make the proxy using a combination of two modules: `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy`.

The syntax was the following:

```
rewriteEngine on
rewriteRule proxy/(.+)$ http://news.example.com/$1 [P]
```

The [P] at the end is telling the rule "act as a proxy" and doesn't work without mod_proxy. Without it, apache makes a "redirect" (the url at the top of the page changes) instead of "just serving the page".

Answer (score 2):

You want the [ProxyPass Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

```
ProxyPass /proxy/news/a http://news.example.com/news/a
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer put me on the right track! At the end, I had to combine mod_proxy with mod_rewrite though - I couldn't make ProxyPass work as you wrote there.

Answer (score 0):

Apache can be configured to use apache:

consider this working sample code (proxy part):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ci.testserver.com
    ServerAlias ci
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```