# No support for indexOf in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a requirement where I create radio buttons dynamically based upon JSON response. So far what I did works in Chrome and firefox, but gives `Object doesn't support this property or method` on `if(subItem[1].indexOf(",") >= 0)` line

My code

```
$("#sList").live("change", function(){
    var currentService=this.value;
    var c1Svc=[];
    var c2Svc=[];

    if(absP.length==2)
    {
        $.each(compareServiceData,function(i,item){

            if(currentService==item[0])
            {
                var configCount=0;
                $.each(item[1],function(j,subItem){

                    var temp=subItem[1];

                    /*The JSON response contains List of Lists, so here if it contains a list it will be separated by "," so split it and store in a array, else directly store in a array*/
                    if(subItem[1].indexOf(",") >= 0)
                    {
                        var tList=temp.split(",");
                        $.each(tList,function(k,val){
                            if(configCount==0)
                            {
                                c1Svc.push(val);                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                c2Svc.push(val);                                
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(configCount==0)
                        {
                            c1Svc.push(subItem[1]);                             
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            c2Svc.push(subItem[1]);                             
                        }
                    }
                    configCount++;

                });
            }

        });

        if ($("#customServiceListing").length == 0)
        {               
            $("#compareContent").append('<table id="customServiceListing" align="center" width="90%" class="csm-table" border="1"><tbody><tr><td><form id="c1Service"></form></td><td><form id="c2Service"></form></td></tr></tbody></table>');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#c1Service').empty();
            $('#c2Service').empty();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $("#compareContent").append('<table align="center" width="90%" class="csm-table" border="1"><tbody><tr><td><form><select id="c1Service"></select></form></td><td><select id="c2Service"></select></td><td><select id="c3Service"></select></td></tr></tbody></table>');
    }


    /*adding service radios to config1*/
    $.each(c1Svc,function(i,item){
        $("#c1Service").append('<input type="radio" name="customConfig1ServiceNames" id="'+item+'" value="'+i+1+'"/>'+item);
    });
    if(c1Svc.length>1)
        $("#c1Service").append('<br/>');

    /*adding service radios to config2*/
    $.each(c2Svc,function(i,item){
        $("#c2Service").append('<input type="radio" name="customConfig2ServiceNames" id="'+item+'" value="'+i+1+'"/>'+item);
    });
    if(c2Svc.length>1)
        $("#c2Service").append('<br/>');
});
```

**Update**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc) is a List of various function code not supported by IE8

**Update**
What is the problem here, for every value it gives me `-1` I am using code given by Sudhir

`alert(subItem[1].indexOf(",")+", "+subItem[1]);`

Screenshot

[image]

**Update**

Got it here, `var temp=subItem[1].toString();` was the problem, converting it to String worked.

Comment: Yep, gotta love IE.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers

Comment: Yep, gotta love IE.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers

Comment: IE is always years behind all other browsers. This is the second similar question I've seen this morning asking about something not working in IE that works everywhere else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IE versions < 9 don't have `indexOf`, so you can add your own:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (elt /*, from*/) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;
        var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
        from = (from < 0) ? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);
        if (from < 0) from += len;

        for (; from < len; from++) {
            if (from in this && this[from] === elt) return from;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

---

```
var subItem = [];
subItem[1]="CSMTestPWXListinerService,CSMTestPWXListinerService_ManualyAdded";
console.log(subItem[1].indexOf(","));
//returns 25
```

Comment: @Mef It should be `>>>`. The bitwise [zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.3E.3E.3E_(Zero-fill_right_shift) bitwise operator ensures that the `length` value is an integer and positive.

Comment: @Rob OK fine, I was mistaking it for escaping, as the whole code was `<pre>`'d and escaped ^^

Comment: @Sudhir: I used indexOf code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc) but when I write `alert(subItem[1].indexOf(","));` where `subItem[1]=CSMTestPWXListinerService,CSMTestPWXListinerService_ManualyAdded" it returns `-1` i.e., always it returns `-1`. What is wrong?

Comment: its working fine for me.. see added code in answer

Comment: update, I am using ur code now, but still I get `-1` for every value

Comment: @Sudhir: Please see my updated question, whats wrong with it?

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: Tested in IE6, 7 & 8 and they all seem to work fine with the code

Comment: @Sudhir: but did you see the screenshot I provided, it is somehow giving me `-1` for `CSMTestPWXListinerService,CSMTestPWXListinerService_ManualyAdded` too. Any ideas, where I might be mistaken?

Comment: Check my update to find out what was the problem. Thanks Sudhir

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx

MS has said that it support indexof() to IE8 as well!

Comment: Well you're looking in the wrong place. [It's not supported.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679977(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: So MS Supports indexOf for String but not for Array! isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this instead?:

```
if(temp.indexOf(",") >= 0)
```

I know I've had cases where it seemed to not understand what the object type was when reference from an array instead of a variable created from the contents of that array location. It doesn't make sense that this would be the case, but I've used it as a workaround before.