# Can't Implementing A* on IE?

Tags: javascript, html, a-star

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for IE browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers)
>   [No support for indexOf in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768574/no-support-for-indexof-in-ie-8)

I'm trying to make a pacman game and everything was going fine until IE came along.

I'm using the astar code from this website: http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/astar-search-algorithm-in-javascript

For some reason, it works fine on all the other browers except IE where I get this error msg every single time.

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'
>   graph.js, line 112 character 9

This is how I've gone about calling the function.

```
var graph = new Graph(MazeMap);
var start = graph.nodes[rows][columns];
var end = graph.nodes[targetRow][targetColumn];
var result = astar.search(graph.nodes, start, end);
```

Comment: Try adding an implementation for the `indexOf` function to the String prototype before including "graph.js"

Comment: Might help to show whats on line 122 of graph.js....

Comment: this is what is on line 122
        this.sinkDown(this.content.indexOf(node));
frankly speaking I am still kinda loss at how the code this guy used for his a* algorithm works.

Comment: Ok so IE doesn't support use of .indexOf(), and from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers I see that there is a way to go round it, but what exactly should I use to replace .indexOf()?

Comment: Older versions of IE do not support `.indexOf` on arrays (while other browsers in "contemporary" versions have for some time). Use a shim script like https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim to paper over this problem (and others).

Comment: Demos of webshim Array polyfills: http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/es5.html Get use to "IE sank my battleship" complaints. It's a common gripe, although we hold out hope it is improving overall.

Comment: The error is actually from [*graph.js*](https://raw.github.com/bgrins/javascript-astar/master/graph.js).

Comment: okay found a solution posted on another thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768574/no-support-for-indexof-in-ie-8?lq=1

Thanks for all the help guys ^^

Comment: +1 for `everything was going fine until IE came along` love it :)