# what is the alternate function for indexOf for string in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have used **indexOf** to check whether i have particular text is present in a sentence or not like the following

```
var temp = "";
temp="data not available";
if(temp.indexOf("datas") == 0){
    alert("True");
}
else{
    alert("false");
}
```

The problem i was facing is **indexOf** is not supported in **Internet Explorer 8**. How to perform this operation in IE8 too? Is there any **default alternate functions** available in jquery?

I tried **inArray** but it supports only array.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/nC9tS/)

Comment: add it as [given](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: One of solution is given here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: you can find answer in so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768574/no-support-for-indexof-in-ie-8

Comment: @RC. This is not duplicate am asking for string not for array and also am asking whether any default function available or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers

Comment: You can convert string into array using `string.split();` Then apply `jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan will it be best practice????

Comment: @PandiyanCool It works, good practice is my first comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're confused about which `indexOf()` is supported.

You're using [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which is supported from IE6 onwards, according to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53xtt423%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

It's [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) that's only supported from IE9 onwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to use String.prototype.indexOf() ? could you please give me a example. I was so confused.

Comment: @PandiyanCool You don't need to change anything; it will just work the way you have it. Though, I'm not sure what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: when i run the code it shows error on page in IE8. Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: The code you've shared works absolutely fine; perhaps the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Okay jack i will check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search):

```
var temp = "data not available";
if(!temp.search("datas")){
    alert("True");
} else {
    alert("false");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/K2WSV/1/)

(NB: I don't have IE8 to test it)