# Getting actual array index from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Let's say I have the following array

```
$scope.stuff = [
    {name: "one", order: 1},
    {name: "three", order: 3},
    {name: "two", order: 2}
]
```

Then I list it using `ng-repeat` like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, data) in stuff | orderBy:'-order'">
    {{ data.name }} - {{ key }} - {{ $index }}
    <br />
</div>
```

It then would display:

```
1 - 0 - 0
2 - 1 - 1
3 - 2 - 2
```

I'd like to be able to know where in the ACTUAL array, these items are coming from in `$scope.stuff`

So I'd like to know that `3` is actually in array index **1** in `$scope.stuff` and not just array index *2* in my sorted `ng-repeat`.

I'm new to angular but does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you are using `orderBy`, is that necessary too?

Comment: @maddog it is necessary, which is why I think i'm having such a hard time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think ng-repeat has anything to get this functionality, but i used the array indexof method to get the actual index.

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, data) in stuff | orderBy:'-order'">
    {{ data.name }} - {{ key }} - {{ $index }} - {{stuff.indexOf(data)}}
    <br />
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xjTZ6Y3xFqs6Bs3LGJk6

Comment: What's the browser compatibility of angular's indexOf?

Comment: ah okay, thanks Kathir. So I guess it would be safe to assume that I can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9768663/2761425) to make sure it works in ie8?

Comment: I dont think ie8 implements this functionality. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers you can follow the answer from that question to fix it across.