# Javascript .indexOf not working on an int array

Tags: javascript, indexof

Code:

```
function showlayer(name){
    var size = js_array.length
    var index = js_array.indexOf(name);
    var plusOne = js_array[index+1];
    document.write("" + name + "<br />" + js_array + "<br />" + index + "<br />" +
                   plusOne + "<br />" )
    ...
}
```

Output:

```
301
300,299,301,290,303,304,302,310,291,306,308,305,307,292,294,295,309
-1
300
```

All possible values of name are in the array, but for some reason indexOf() never finds them. Whats up?

Comment: Are you comparing numbers to strings?

Comment: This isn't the problem you are specifically seeing here, but it is worth pointing out that `Array.indexOf()` isn't available on IE8 and lower. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc.

Comment: @pseudosavant Yeah I know. Hope it won't be too much of an issue

Comment: That stackoverflow link has a polyfill to add support for `Array.indexOf()` to IE6-8 if you need it. I prefer to only support IE9 and up now-a-days, but there are still a lot of IE8 people out there.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
...
var index = js_array.indexOf(parseInt(name, 10)); // so that it does not try to compare strings...
...
```

Comment: @gta0004 happy to help ^_^

Comment: @gta0004: Apparently, `name` is not an int.

Comment: @SLaks hehe that is most probably `true`.

Comment: @SLaks look at the output. 301 = name.
so idk

Comment: @gta0004 output `typeof name` and your shall see ^_^

Comment: Or, simply cast the key to Int: `array.indexOf(+name)`.