# Get array index by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to get array index by value.

I have this code:

```
var squares = new Array();
for (var i = 1; i <= 160; i++) {
    squares.push(i);
}

angular.element('.click').click(function () {
    var squareId = angular.element(this).attr('id');
    var fisk = squares.indexOf(squareId);
    console.log(fisk);
});
```

This only returns -1, thus, It can't be found. If a replace squareId with a number in indeOf, it works perfect, but if I use a variable, It don't work.

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**See Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8gkqxL1/)

It's because the variable `squareId` could be returning a string value. The function `indexOf` can't find the string because it has numbers in the array.

```
// string search
var squareId = '2';
var fisk = squares.indexOf(squareId);
console.log('This will not be found ' + fisk);

// number search
var squareId = Number('2');
var fisk = squares.indexOf(squareId);
console.log('This will be found ' + fisk);
```

See [**similar question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592115/javascript-indexof-not-working-on-an-int-array)

Comment: How can I convert all my numbers in the array to string?

Comment: like this `squares.push('' + i);` or `i.toString()` :) @user500468

Comment: @user500468 see http://jsfiddle.net/y8gkqxL1/2/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5765401

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing your array values with numbers between 1 and 160, so squares.indexOf(1) for example would return 0.

What you want to do is initialize the array with the actual ids of your elements.